# How do you reset the stored credentials in 'git credential-osxkeychain'?

Tags: macos, git, github

I've followed the GitHub instructions for setting up my account, and I'm able to clone, but I'm unable to push remotely.

When I do a "git push" I get the 403 error. It has the correct URL. I tried a "git credential-osxkeychain get" to see what it was giving, and this prints out the wrong credentials.

I believe what happened is the first time it asked for the credentials, I thought it was another application asking, and it put the wrong ones in.

I just need to reset it so that it uses the correct keychain item for my GitHub account.

I've tried:

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase
git credential-osxkeychain set
```

The program never gives any prompts. Set will say "bad input" if I don't do the right thing. I tried putting in "`password=password`", etc., but then when I do a "get" I still get the old ones.

I can't figure out where these are being stored, as they are not in .gitconfigure. Further there are no recent keychain items that could be it. (I have several GitHub accounts in my keychain and it is not using any of them.)

Comment: Related, credential helper agnostic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21745213/changed-github-password-no-longer-able-to-push-back-to-the-remote

Comment: Likely the same on Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git

Comment: [You can set this helper utility to associate your login with specific repos rather than entire domains, in case you want to use multiple accounts.  More on that here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31351376/1922144)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The solution turned out to be this:

The command `git credential-osxkeychain` was using the *first* GitHub account entry in my keychain.  This one was not the one that had access to the projects in question.

I resolved the problem by touching the account in Keychain Access so that its date changed (I think I just changed the comment) and now that it became the most recent GitHub account it became the first one returned to credential-osxkeychain, and thus everything worked.

A better form of support for multiple GitHub accounts would be nice, but it is likely that most people only have one primary account and don't run into this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how this works for multiple users on the same host, but you might check out ssh and using a `~/.ssh/config` file instead of using OSX Keychain.  This is used in cases where you may have multiple ssh keys for different hosts(and thinking accounts as well).

http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/

Answer (score 233):

From Terminal:
(You need to enter the following three lines)

```
 $ git credential-osxkeychain erase ⏎
 host=github.com  ⏎
 protocol=https   ⏎
 ⏎
 ⏎
```

NOTE: after you enter “protocol=https” above you need to press ~~RETURN~~ TWICE (Each '⏎' is equivalent to a 'press enter/return' )

Comment: For some reason I couldn't find any Git/GitHub credentials within the Keychain app, but this worked. Thanks!

Comment: Since this wasn’t clear to me: you have to enter all 3 lines above, and then press return again – i.e. lines 2/3 above are not output from the command, but input.

Comment: The number of entering the enter key was the key.

Comment: can anyone please explain what this does? @maz

Comment: @Ojasvsingh it removes the github.com entry from your keychain. This means that the next time you attempt to connect it will be detected that there isn't an entry anymore. This means you will be prompted for your current credentials for the github.com

Comment: @Frederik I agree, the people who write git documentation at git think the users are mind readers.  They are from planet "git" where everybody speaks gittish and should just assume.

Comment: Why is this `git` command so abstruse. `git credential-osxkeychain --help` doesn't seem to give any documentation. UPDATE [someone else noticed this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51294589/5783745), and yep, it's more or less undocumented. Kinda wild since it has an unusual usage (pressing enter *twice*?!).

Answer (score 95):

I'm not sure how to erase through the command line, but it's fairly easily to do it through the Keychain Access app. Just go to Applications -> Utilties -> Keychain Access, then enter "github.com". You can either delete the invalid item or update the password from with the app.

Comment: If someone reading this figures out how to do from the command line, would be nice to know.

Comment: @funroll The command line tool is `security`. The man page states it has a `delete-internet-password` command.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'm sure that will be useful to someone.

Comment: From which keychain?

Answer (score 43):

Try this in your command line.

`git config --local credential.helper ""`

It works for me every time when I have multiple GitHub accounts in OSX keychain

Comment: This may not be the accepted answer basing on the question's title but it's definitely useful in the context that the questioner was trying to achieve. If your password has changed and git "remembers" the old one, simply run this command and try again. Thanks invinciblemuffi.

Comment: It is so useful for different user login. Very thank you !

Comment: Glad that a simple solution helps the community around :)

Comment: this is the only answer that has worked for me on mac

Comment: Once the password is reset, for mac, running `git config --local credential.helper "osxkeychain"` re-enables the credential helper so git does not keep asking for the password going forward

Comment: Exactly what I needed after I've changed my password!

Answer (score 10):

git-credential-osxkeychain stores passwords in the Apple Keychain, as noted above.

By default, gitcredentials only considers the domain name. If you want Git to consider the full path (e.g. if you have multiple GitHub accounts), set the `useHttpPath` variable to `true`, as described at http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials.html. Note that changing this setting will ask your credentials again for each URL.

Answer (score 10):

On Mac, use the command `git credential-osxkeychain erase`.

OR remove manually from keychain from *Applications* → *Utilities* → *Keychain Access*. Then remove the github.com keychain. Then use push; it will ask for the keychain access; then deny.

It will ask for the new username and password, add it then pushes a file for that.

**After `git push` I found this error. Then I use the upper case-
issue:**

> remote: Permission to user1/file.git denied to user2(previously exist
>   user  ). fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx/':
>   The requested URL returned error: 403

Answer (score 6):

You can delete existing credentials and add new ones via "Keychain Access"

[image]

Ref. https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain

Comment: This is the same comment and link as the one above by gorjanz. Furthermore, changing the credentials from the keychain isn't always possible, e.g. if you have more than one entry in keychain and don't know which one is the right one. In this case see my comment under gorjanz's post.

Answer (score 5):

GitHub help page for this issue:
https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/

Comment: That link only tells you how to update your credentials from the app. If you don't want to do that (I couldn't because I had several github entries in the keychain and couldn't tell which was the right one) you can use the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68824590/update-command-line-git-credential-helper-for-personal-access-tokens-pat-on-gi): You can invalidate your credentials via `$ echo url=https://account@github.com | git credential reject` (replace `account` with your account). Next time you push, git will prompt you for your password and store it.

Answer (score 4):

Try running `/Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access`.

Answer (score 3):

@bk2204 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68825235/61505) only worked for me from terminal:

```
$ echo url=https://github.com | git credential reject
```

Comment: True. It is [documented with Git 2.42 (Q3 2023)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76592430/6309)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it directly through the keychain app itself. Find exactly the entry with Kind='Internet password' and Name='url where your remote git repository is located'. Then change the account and PAT token in password field
[image: keyChain]