# How to change the GitHub user?

Tags: git, github

I would like to change to another GitHub user. I removed the github.com Keychain entry and also tried to remove it via the command line (https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain) but when I try to push commits using `user2` the following error appears:

```
ERROR: Permission to user2/test-repo.git denied to user1.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

My .gitconfig contains this:

```
[credential]
  helper = osxkeychain
```

What can I do to remove the credentials from `user1`?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/11583503/6309 help?

Comment: I removed all matching keys using `git credential-osxkeychain erase` but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution. It works when I clone the repo using HTTPS.

```
git clone https://github.com/user2/test-repo.git
```

When I try to push, I'm able to insert my new credentials and can push successful. YEHH!!!

Answer (score 1):

Hey thanks for your answer. I cloned the repo using the new user, this works probably because it's a public repo but I can't push. The output from `git remote -v` is this:

```
origin  git@github.com:user2/test-repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:user2/test-repo.git (push)
```

I can't find out where my old username is saved ...

Answer (score 0):

What is the url of your repo in your .git/config file.

looks like you have cloned the repo using http/https so he user name and passwords are in your file.

Check youir remote settigns:

```
git remote -v
```

The url needs to be something like

```
ssh://git@.../repo.git;
```

If the url doesn't start with ssh your ssh key are not used

To set up your ssh url you can either edit the config file or use command line.

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@ip:port/repo.git
```