# How to reset credentials in macosxkeychain?

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

I tried destroying my credentials with `git credential-osxkeychain erase` and that didn't work. I also went into my Keychain Access application and searched for git and github and could not find the keychain.

I even looked at the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067818/how-do-you-reset-the-stored-credentials-in-git-credential-osxkeychain) but it doesn't help because there is nothing in my Keychain Access application. How else can I update my information?

I don't want to just reclone repositories and then push.

Comment: Please specify your question and avoid the [`XY problem`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What you have written so far seems to be about the solutions you tried not about the problem you have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you reset the stored credentials in git credential-osxkeychain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067818/how-do-you-reset-the-stored-credentials-in-git-credential-osxkeychain)