# Git stopped showing a prompt to unlock the SSH key after changing the password on github account

Tags: git, github

Recently I have change the password on my github account. After that my ssh-agent stopped showing the GUI promt to unlock the SSH key. Hence, I can not perform pushing and fetching to/from my remote repos. SSH agent remebers the password for the github account (not the password to unlock the SSH keys). How do I change that one?

Comment: Use `git credential`, q.v. [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067818/how-do-you-reset-the-stored-credentials-in-git-credential-osxkeychain).

Answer (score 1):

You can reset git stored credentials using following commands

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=github.com
protocol=https
<press return>
```

Please check this link for more details 
https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/