# Git configuration to pull/push WITH password

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine on Macbook Pro using the VMware Fusion. My git repository can be accessed from OSX and from Ubuntu (as shared directory) as well, however the git communication with BitBucket works differently - the `git pull` and `git push` commands ask for password in Ubuntu, but they work without password in OSX.

Configuration files:

- The `/etc/gitconfig` file is absent in both cases
- The `~/.gitconfig` file content is the same in both cases
- The `.git/config` file is physically the same

Git version on Ubuntu is 1.9.1, and on OSX - 1.9.5.

Where should I look to find out the reason for this difference? I'd actually prefer entering password in OSX as well, because it's a semi-private machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where should I look to find out the reason for this difference?

It depends on the url used (output of `git remote -v`)

- **https**: the OSX session might have [cached the password with the oskeychain helper](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/#platform-mac).
  You would need a [cache credential helper in Ubuntu](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/#platform-linux) to achieve the same result.
- **ssh**: git is looking for the ssh keys in `~/.ssh`, which can be properly set in the Mac OSX session, but empty in the Ubuntu VM.
  You would need the same keys in the Ubuntu `~/.ssh` folder in order to avoid ssh to fall back to a username/password authentication.

Comment: My remote repo is configured with `https:`, and this configuration is the same for both cases, because there is actually a single `.git/config` file. Nevertheless I've synced both `.ssh` dirs just in case. I'll check the `oskeychain` helper, but I actually need authentication *with password* - thanks!

Comment: @HEKTO If the MAc OSX session does *not* ask for a password, it means said password is cached in a way which is not accessible by the Ubuntu session.

Comment: @HEKTO If you actually need authentication with password, you can clear up that cache: https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/ (http://stackoverflow.com/q/11067818/6309)

Answer (score 1):

Please use SSH to pull/push without password.

Refer: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html

> When you use HTTPS, you authenticate (supply a username and password) each time you take an action that requires a connection with Bitbucket. Who wants to do that? This page shows you how to use secure shell (SSH) to communicate with the Bitbucket server and avoid having to manually type a password all the time.

**Step 1**: Gen ssh key, From the Terminal or Git Bash

```
ssh-keygen
```

**Step 2**: Confirm the default path .ssh/id_rsa
Enter a passphrase (recommended) or leave it blank.
Remember this passphrase, as you will need it to unlock the
key whenever you use it.

**Step 3**: Open *~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub* and copy & paste the contents into
your server.

**Note** that *id_rsa.pub* is your public key and can be shared,
while *id_rsa* is your private key and should be kept secret.

**Step 4**: Re-Check, in Git Bash type

```
ssh -p 29418 YOUR_NAME@YOUR_SERVER.com
```

to check result. if success

> ****    Welcome to Gerrit Code Review    ****
>
> Hi , you have successfully connected over
>   SSH.
>
> git clone
>   ssh://YOUR_NAME@YOUR_SERVER.com:29418/REPOSITORY_NAME.git

**Step 5**: Change remote directory of git. Type in Git Bash to replace your link.

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://YOUR_NAME@YOUR_SERVER.com:29418/REPOSITORY_NAME.git
```