# update local github account information

Tags: git, github, git-config

Unable to make commits to my new github account repositories from my local terminal.

```
remote: Permission to <new-account-name>/22c.git denied to <old-account-name>.
```

I have updated my global 'git config' settings`

```
git config --list
```

reveals the following:

```
credential.helper=osxkeychain
core.editor=/usr/bin/vim
core.autocrlf=input
user.name=<new-account-name>
user.email=<new-email>
push.default=simple
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/<new-account-name>/22c.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

thank you for the help, let me know if there is anything else that would help solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `user.name=<new-account-name>` has nothing to do with authentication to GitHub as `<new-account-name>`: it is just about authorship associated to commits.

Your credentials are probably cached in your [git credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) osxkeychain: you need to update them there.
See "[Updating credentials from the OSX Keychain](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/)". In command line:

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=github.com
protocol=https
[Press Return]
```

> If it's successful, nothing will print out.
>   To test that it works, try and clone a repository from GitHub. If you are prompted for a username/password, the keychain entry was deleted.

See more at "[How do you reset the stored credentials in git credential-osxkeychain?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11067818/6309)".

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in my, osxkeychain. click [here](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/) for a well documented solution.