# Cannot clone github repo without being logged in as root, regardless of sudo

Tags: git, macos, unix

Running on OSX ->

```
git clone https://github.com/.../project.git
Cloning into 'project'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/.../project.git/' not found

...:repos ...$ sudo git clone https://github.com/.../project.git
Cloning into 'project'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/.../project.git/' not found


...:repos ...$ sudo su


sh-3.2# git clone https://github.com/.../project.git
Cloning into 'project'...
remote: Counting objects: 122, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (93/93), done.
remote: Total 122 (delta 28), reused 114 (delta 20), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (122/122), 364.08 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (28/28), done.
```

Another weird thing about this is that this is a private repo and it does not ask for my password when I'm root. I assume it is stored somewhere.

EDIT :  the solution is to delete the existing keychain element in the osx keychain

Comment: The OS X credential helpers for Git use the OS X keychain routines to provide https credentials. sudo apparently has no effect on keychain info.

Comment: @torek so what do I do to fix this

Comment: I don't know, I'm no expert on OS X keychain. (I normally use ssh access anyway since it works from all systems.)

Comment: What happen when you run sh command in terminal and run git again?

Comment: @SamuelTulach When run with sh I get the same not found output: 

sh-3.2$ git push
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository ... not found

Comment: @Ryan Did you before add any login details to git with root (sudo) enabled?

Comment: @SamuelTulach I'm not sure, is there any way that I could remove them if I did?

Comment: @Ryan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067818/how-do-you-reset-the-stored-credentials-in-git-credential-osxkeychain also try to reset cache.

Comment: @torek can some helper bash command can fix this?

Comment: @SamuelTulach Thank you for your help. When I saw your post it mentioned to possibly reset the osx keychain by deleting the existing credentials, and that worked! Then I just had to run a chown on the directory and I was good to go! If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Does anything from this page help? https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/

Comment: @ScottNewson, I found the solution. The problem is the osx keychain and you have to delete your credentials and remake them. I have asked Samuel to post an answer but torek also helped so whoever posts first I will accept.

Comment: @Ryan you can also an answer yourself and accept it if you like

Comment: There is a bounty and i would like it to go to one of those two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to delete your github credentials in osxkeychain, and then you can recreate them.

Comment: this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are still logged but not with the good account for accessing to your project.
For that reason, github doesn’t ask you your credential (username/password) and fail when trying to access to your project.

1. So, if `credential.helper` is set with osxkeychain you can reset your GitHub element in the `osxkeychain`. Credential helper is used for remembering GitHub credentials. Especially, on Mac OSX 10.7 and above, osxkeychain helper is automatically included in your Git installation.
2. Then you can also do not use the osxkeychain credential helper by unsetting it:

   ```
   git config --global --unset credential.helper
   (--system should be unset if your credential helper is set here)
   ```
3. Otherwise, if you have already not credential.helper set You should unset github.user and github.token

   ```
   $git config --global --unset github.user
   $git config --global --unset github.token
   ```

Comment: what exactly is a github user, token, and credentiel helper? For example, github.user is either my github username or my computer username, and I have no idea what I would put for token and credential helper... even githubs documentation isn't clear : https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The solution is not what you described: the solution is to delete the existing keychain element in the osx keychain. If you update your answer with the correct answer, I will accept the answer and award you the reputation. The bounty expires in 1 day or it is lost.

Comment: @Ryan Created a separate answer with your actual solution.