# Why is there no documentation anywhere for git credential-osxkeychain?

Tags: git, macos

This is really frustrating.  Typing `git credential-osxkeychain` tells me:

```
usage: git credential-osxkeychain <get|store|erase>
```

so I know it's installed.  But `git help credential-osxkeychain` says there's no help, and I can find nothing on the web that explains what get, store, and erase actually do.

What I ultimately want to do is get my git passwords stored in the keychain,  but that's a different story.  I just can't believe there is no documentation for the command.

(Yes, I know this is a "why" question, but obviously I'm asking for where I can find documentation)

Comment: What happens when you do `git help credential-osxkeychain`?

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but see https://stackoverflow.com/q/11067818/1256452

Comment: Oops, that's what I meant to type on the third line.  Fixed in edit.

Comment: I also wondered the [same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067818/how-do-you-reset-the-stored-credentials-in-git-credential-osxkeychain#comment133917043_28007050). Weird that it isn't documented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature comes from [commit 34961d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34961d30dae69b00a8a5aabd568fb87f376ebb87), introduced by [Jeff King](https://github.com/peff) in Dec. 2011 for Git 1.7.9.

And... it did not come with any formal documentation.
You can see more Git Pro Book "[Git Tools - Credential Storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage)", which is the only form of documentation mentioning osxkeychain.

> Does this mean it doesn't apply to ssh access? That's what my repo uses

Exactly: *any* credential helper (osxkeychain or otherwise) would apply only for HTTPS URLs, *not* SSH.
And SSH needs a cache only if the private key is passphrase-protected (in which case an [ssh agent is needed](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent)).

Comment: Interesting... I see that the commit comment says it is for storing git-over-http passwords...  Does this mean it doesn't apply to ssh access?  That's what my repo uses.

Comment: @AgentFriday Yes, http(s) only. See my edited answer.

Comment: I think I just need the instructions to store ssh credentials, which I'm sure is well documented.  Thanks.

Comment: @AgentFriday Yes, hence the link I mention in the answer: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent