# Git issue Pushing

Tags: git, github

I have just started working with Git and Github again, I can't seem to push material to a repo I have cloned from my Github account.

I keep getting this:

> remote: Permission to tapherjspiteri/tapherjblog.git denied to
>
> csolvex. fatal: unable to access

Any help appreciated. I used to use **git** with my **csolvex** account but that was more than a year ago. I would like to figure out how to clear this up so I can start studying again.

Comment: The fastest way to get there. Clone your repo with SSH link.

Comment: Have you gone through the github docs on using https or ssh to clone? https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/

Comment: I will look into this if this saves me from having to enter username and password. I appreciate the suggestion and the link forward.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:-
1) git add . 
2) git commit
3) git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git (your git project link this is for example link so be remind)
4) git push origin master

Comment: I tried this still getting same answer.  Is there anyway of clear the git info on my computer so I can start over again. I used to use the user name csolvex with an account that I have that is not personal.

Comment: What does the denied to csolvex mean? Is this an option set on my notebook?

Comment: csolvex account  is a working or not? because i have check this account not exits if u check and inform i will help u

Comment: The issue is resolved. The csolvex account was an old set of credentials from a job I had. They got locked into my os x keychain

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone's suggestions, I figured out it must be something with a previously stored password and username. I found some questions posted in stackoverflow regarding resetting the git information, I then found this link:

[How do you reset the stored credentials in 'git credential-osxkeychain'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067818/how-do-you-reset-the-stored-credentials-in-git-credential-osxkeychain)

I removed the old credentials and was able to get my material to push.

Regards,

Christopher