# How do you debug git credential helpers?

Tags: git

I have read:

- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage
- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables

  - Specifically in "Debugging", `GIT_TRACE_SETUP` and `GIT_TRACE`
- https://pratz.github.io/custom-git-credential-helper
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28007050/117471

  - …which taught me to test my credential-osxkeychain helper via `echo -e "host=git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\nprotocol=https\n\n" | git credential-osxkeychain get`
- https://kgrz.io/using-git-credential-helpers.html

Unfortunately, I cannot get the most basic Scientific Method™ test to work. I have used [my stand-in command](https://gist.github.com/RichardBronosky/d5d66bfe73cbecbfd73528a61b9728e3) to try and log what happens when git calls the helper. Unfortunately, my command logs nothing. Therefore I'm forced to conclude that git is not calling its helper. What can I do?

Comment: Since asking this, I have have discovered that `credential.helper` doesn't seem to apply to `ssh://` urls. Please correct me if I'm wrong. (Note: I didn't realize this was happening because I had `git config --global url.ssh://git@github.com/.insteadOf https://github.com/` set)

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to get the 1Password CLI to hand over my GitHub token to the `gh` command, and configure Git to use the `gh` command as a credential helper. But I was running into an issue when I would run `gh auth git-credential` from the command line and it would produce the correct credentials, but when I had the following in `~/.gitignore` a `git clone` would still prompt me for my username and password:

```
[credential "https://github.com"]
    helper = /usr/bin/gh auth git-credential
```

To do some debugging, I first enabled [trace logging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_debugging) in Git by setting the `GIT_TRACE` environment variable to `true`:

```
GIT_TRACE=true git clone https://github.com/wheelerlaw/some-private-repo
```

which would yield output that looked like this:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=true git clone https://github.com/Kong/khcp.git
15:19:00.344373 git.c:460               trace: built-in: git clone https://github.com/Kong/khcp.git
Cloning into 'khcp'...
15:19:00.347803 run-command.c:655       trace: run_command: git remote-https origin https://github.com/Kong/khcp.git
15:19:00.349893 git.c:750               trace: exec: git-remote-https origin https://github.com/Kong/khcp.git
15:19:00.349939 run-command.c:655       trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin https://github.com/Kong/khcp.git
15:19:00.625485 run-command.c:655       trace: run_command: '/usr/bin/gh auth git-credential get'
```

However, it wouldn't show any debugging output of the data passed to/from the credential helper. To do this, I wrote a small Python script that acted as a wrapper around the credential helper:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import subprocess


def eprint(*args, **kwargs):
    print(*args, file=sys.stderr, **kwargs)

def etrace(str):
    eprint("[TRACE] ", str)


args = ['/usr/bin/gh', 'auth', 'git-credential'] + sys.argv[1:]

process = subprocess.Popen(args,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=sys.stderr,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                           universal_newlines=True)

etrace(args)
for input in sys.stdin:
    etrace(input.strip())
    process.stdin.write(input)

process.stdin.close()

etrace("Done sending input...")

for output in process.stdout.readlines():
    etrace("Printing output...")
    etrace(output.strip())
    print(output.strip())

etrace("Done receiving output...")

return_code = process.poll()

etrace("Return code: " + str(return_code))

exit(return_code)
```

Then, I modified my `~/.gitconfig` file to call the Python script as the credential helper:

```
[credential "https://github.com"]
    helper = /home/wheeler/wrapper.py
```

Now when I do the same `git clone` command with the trace debugging enabled, I can see how `git` and `gh auth git-credential` are talking to each other:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=true git clone https://github.com/Kong/khcp.git
15:54:33.973855 git.c:460               trace: built-in: git clone https://github.com/Kong/khcp.git
Cloning into 'khcp'...
15:54:33.987155 run-command.c:655       trace: run_command: git remote-https origin https://github.com/Kong/khcp.git
15:54:33.989509 git.c:750               trace: exec: git-remote-https origin https://github.com/Kong/khcp.git
15:54:33.989539 run-command.c:655       trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin https://github.com/Kong/khcp.git
15:54:34.191478 run-command.c:655       trace: run_command: '/home/wheeler/test.py get'
[TRACE]  ['/usr/bin/gh', 'auth', 'git-credential', 'get']
[TRACE]  protocol=https
[TRACE]  host=github.com
[TRACE]  Done sending input...
[TRACE]  Done receiving output...
[TRACE]  Return code: 1
```

This helped me realize that I needed to set my `helper` line to the following to allow the `gh` command to get the token from 1Password:

```
[credential "https://github.com"]
    helper = /usr/bin/op plugin run -- gh auth git-credential
```

Hope this helps