# how to enter Bitbucket password on mac terminal?

Tags: git, macos, terminal, bitbucket

How do I connect to bitbucket on my mac?

I'm trying to import my existing code into bitbucket using terminal on mac, but after I do a "git push -u origin master" it asks for my bitbucket password but it doesn't let me type my password.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you reset the stored credentials in 'git credential-osxkeychain'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067818/how-do-you-reset-the-stored-credentials-in-git-credential-osxkeychain)

Comment: no, I'm trying to input my password to link my repository from my mac to bitbucket

Comment: `git remote add origin` adds a new origin, it does not reset your password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, when you input a password in a terminal, you don't see anything as you do it.  Many graphical environments show you an asterisk or bullet for each character, but the way terminals work is simply that they turn off the echo (that is, the display) of the characters you type.

So when you're typing your password in the terminal, it is being entered, but nothing is being displayed on the terminal, and that's normal.  Just type it in as you usually would, and then hit Enter.