# 'https://': Could not resolve host: info-- Git Hub new security

Tags: git, github, terminal

After GitHub released this statement: "Support for password authentication was removed. Please use a personal access token instead" I enabled 2 factor authentication to my account. That resolved the issue for only one day and now every time i try to push to my repository i get this: 'https://': Could not resolve host: info

I've tried logging out & back in again, re-starting VScode, adding a keychain, deleting my cache & adding osxkeychain again, I have entered my username & email credentials, however, I am never promted for a password.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Support for password authentication was removed. Please use a personal access token instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-to)

Comment: 2 factor authentication is not related to using a personal access token. First is for manual login on the GitHub website, the other is for Git operations.

Comment: If you are getting an error about resolving a host named `info` while using an `https://` URL, you are probably using `https://info/something` as your URL. That is, you've specified that the *host name* for the machine you'd like to call up is `info`. That's not a valid host name, which is why you're getting the error, so check the URL you are using.

Answer (score 0):

> however, I am never prompted for a password.

That means your old password might still be cached by the credential manager.
Check the output of `git config --global credential.helper`

If is is `osxkeychain`, try:

```
printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com" | git-credential-osxkeychain erase
```

(that, or explorer directly [your KeyChain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67566630/6309), or use [`security delete-internet-password`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/235418))
Then try your `git push` again, and see if you are prompted for your token then.

Plus, make sure to use an URL based on the host for which your password is used:

```
 cd /path/to/repo
 git remote -v
 https://github.com/...
 # not
 https://info/...
```