# On linux how do I change the PAT in the git credential.helper?

Tags: git

On linux how do I change the Personal Access Token (PAT) in the `git` `credential-helper`?

```
! [remote rejected]   zippy.v2 -> zippy.v2 (refusing to allow a Personal Access Token to create or update workflow `.github/workflows/build.yml` without `workflow` scope)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/zippy-king/super-project.git'
```

I need a way of resetting the credentials in the store, so I can enter a Personal Access Token (PAT) with all the needed permissions.

Comment: how do you authenticate to Github, what is this question for? fixing your Github Workflow (Github Action) or you want to achieve a specific thing ? For how [`credential.helper` works](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/wiki/How-the-Git-Credential-Managers-works) and for how [update CLI git credential-helper for PAT pat on Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68824590/update-command-line-git-credential-helper-for-personal-access-tokens-pat-on-git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me - it clears the store, when you do "git push" or some action you are asked to enter again the user and password.

```
rm -rf ~/.git-credentials
```