# Git keeps using old GitHub credentials

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to set up multiple account credential management for github using [these](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996) instructions and ran into a problem... Git continues to use my GitHub credentials even when I set up the `user.name` and `user.email` properties in the repo to match the work-related SSH key configuration I set up. No matter what I do, it keeps using my personal GitHub account as I see a request to push to the work repo denied to my personal account.

I've tried [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28007050/284538) to remove any credentials that might have been stored in the macOS keystore. It's behaving like it's completely ignoring the SSH configuration. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

First, `user.name` and `user.email` has nothing to do with credential check (though sometimes it will be checked by server for identifying whether these commits are made by you, but not affect your question).

Second, you didn't mentioned about changing remote or changing repository, and the sites you mentioned didn't talk about it, too. So I am **guessing** what you have met now:

1. You have a local repository, usually `git push` it to your personal account.
2. Now, you want to `git push` the same repo to your work-related account.
3. You tried changing `user.name`, `user.email`, `git credential-helper` (on macOS it is `git credential-osxkeychain`), but those makes nothing, Git keeps warning you that you don't have permission to your **personal** account.
4. You asked [the current question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74091734/9035237).

If so, then I **guess**:

1. You should grant the permission of your working account to your personal account's repository, or
2. You should create a new repository in your working account, and `git remote add` or `git remote set-url` for pushing it to your working account.