# Git - remote: Repository not found UBUNTU

Tags: visual-studio-code, access-token

When I'm cloning a repository from my account this error show up. Also, I can't push to anything to my repositories.

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/username/repo-name.git/' not found
```

after I generate an access token from GitHub issue is still occurring to me.

**commands that I used**

```
git clone https://<token>@github.com/username/repo.git

git push https://<token>@github.com/username/repo.git
```

I'm using

- **VS Code - version 1.62.3**
- **OS - Ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS**

Please anyone can guide me to solve this problem?

Comment: To *really* solve the problem, avoid VSCode. To get around it, upgrade or downgrade VSCode, because a bunch of recent versions are broken.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git authentication with GitHub fails, remote: No anonymous write access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69948454/git-authentication-with-github-fails-remote-no-anonymous-write-access)

Comment: What exact version should I downgrade? @torek

Comment: VSCode - see the link.

Comment: I downgrade looked after that. but the issue is still the same. Now Only the option exists for me git pushing or clone directly from the terminal. @torek