# Git push from Visual Studio Code gives "remote: No anonymous write access"

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push the code from the repository when I encountered this error:

> No anonymous write access.

I have followed the steps mentioned in *[Git push from Visual Studio Code: "No anonymous write access. Authentication failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60757334/git-push-from-vs-code-no-anonymous-write-access-authentication-failed)*, but still, I got the same error.

I need some clarifications for the process mentioned in that question.

After doing the `cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub`, I saw the key in the format

```
ssh-ed25519 <key> <email>
```

Do I need to copy the whole thing in the `key field` of GitHub account like key+email or only key?

[image]

Is there another solution too apart from the clarification?

I copied all the content as per the answers I received. But then, I changed my remote from a `https` to a `ssh` link, and then I am getting this error while pushing:

```
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Comment: There is now a candidate for the canonical question for this update scandal: *[fatal: Authentication failed for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979522/)* (despite the unspecific title)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Clarified:  Copy the whole thing in the key field of the GitHub account.

   `ssh-ed25519 <key> <email>`
2. If the error still persists after following the tutorial given in [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60757334/git-push-from-vs-code-no-anonymous-write-access-authentication-failed), then change the remote of the repository from `https` to `ssh` using

   ```
   git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<username>/<reponame>.git
   ```
3. Now if you encounter the error

   ```
      sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
      git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
      fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
      Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
   ```

   Never forget to add the SSH key from where you are pushing the code:

   ```
    ssh-add
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Copy everything as it is from your public key `something.pub` to the `key` section of the GitHub SSH settings page.

The key should be like this: `ssh-rsa <key> <username>@<machine_name>`

Comment: It is like `ssh-ed25519 <key> <email_registered on github>` in my case.

Comment: not sure if git support Edwards methods of ssh.

Comment: found this article [reference](https://gist.github.com/hrdtbs/ba50868d7d608b89f958fe32dc35fdd4)

Comment: I refer from here https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent to generate the key.

Comment: So for the reference you share , I copied already from here,but then I changed my remote from `https` to `ssh` link , then I am getting this error while pushing.

`sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: was the key generated for the user is same user you use to push the code to remote repo?

Comment: Yes @ruben, since I don't have any other key exisiting.

Comment: Solved the issue @ruben, solution will be posted in answers section.

Comment: Was ssh-add does the work?

Answer (score 0):

You can read here to test your SSH connection before pushing your code to remote: [Test SSH connection on GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign)

Comment: I appreciate it !