# Error "remote: No anonymous write access" pushing to GitHub

Tags: git, github

I can't push to my repository. It displays me this error:

> remote: No anonymous write access.

How can I log in to my GitHub account. I know the login username and password, but Git doesn't ask me about it. I use HTTPS.

Comment: try this https://github.community/t/no-anonymous-write-access/211937/11

Comment: Also i trying to push form vscode?

Comment: I also got the same error couple days of ago. Please refer to the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69963454/git-push-from-visual-studio-code-gives-remote-no-anonymous-write-access

Comment: Yes but I can't pushed via terminal too

Comment: Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70015104/edit) more information to your question (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today)? What Git client do you use? Are you using Visual Studio Code as the Git client and recently updated it (to 1.62.2)? Then a candidate for the canonical question for this particular problem caused by the update of Visual Studio Code to 1.62.2 in October/November 2021 is *[Fix for "fatal: Authentication failed for"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979522/)* (despite the unspecific title).

Answer (score 0):

To push your project to the GitHub repository, follow the following steps:

1. To connect to your repository, use the below command

   ```
    git remote add origin "URL of the repository"
   ```
2. `git push origin`
3. `git pull origin`

Or, if you are using Visual Studio Code or any other text editor:

Just clone the empty repository at start using Git Bash and then you can push and pull.