# Git pushes from Visual Studio Code is failing

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

My goal was to push my added and committed files from Visual Studio Code to GitHub. I expected it to work after I pressed the "Pull and Push" button. It turns out, something is wrong. I looked at the error and the following is what it said.

```
> git push origin main:main
remote: No anonymous write access.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/xItzDiamondx/school.git/'
```

I attempted signing out of one of my accounts and then signing in to the account that owns the repository that I'm trying to commit to, but to no avail.

Comment: [Does it help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60757334/git-push-from-visual-studio-code-no-anonymous-write-access-authentication-fai)

Comment: @phd That error did show up after the update, so maybe that will work.

Comment: A candidate for the canonical question for this particular problem caused by the update to Visual Studio Code to 1.62.2 in October/November 2021 is *[Fix for "fatal: Authentication failed for"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979522/)* (despite the unspecific title).