# Git using non-default/ unrelated user

Tags: git, github

Observe the below -

```
$ git config --global user.email 
SOME_EMAIL@gmail.com
$ git config user.email 
SOME_EMAIL@gmail.com
$ git push
remote: Permission to vishvAsa/bhAShAntaram.git denied to <DIFFERENT_USERNAME>.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/vishvAsa/bhAShAntaram.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

what's going on? why's the right user id not being used?

(PS: I don't want to set the desired username in the remote url - too many repositories to fix. And I want `git config --global credential.helper store`. Also, I am on Debian 12 KDE. )

I tried several tips from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615431/git-pushes-with-wrong-user-from-terminal?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top), but the solutions proposed there (`git config --global push.default simple`, `git config --global --unset credential.helper`) don't work. Also, `ssh-add -l` returns empty and `ssh -T git@github.com` doesn't connect. Explicitly adding the right key with ssh-add doesn't help.  Undoing `git config --global credential.helper store` helped for one particular repo (I got asked the username), though another keeps assuming the wrong git username.

Comment: Is there a config for the repo level overriding your global?

Comment: No. `git config user.email` shows that too, right?

Comment: The [`user.email` and `user.name` settings](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-username) have absolutely nothing to do with any usernames; they're just text that's added to the "author" and/or "committer" field of new commits you create.