# Multiple GIT accounts configured on same machine, one with Gerrit and another with GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-bash, gerrit

I have 2 GIT accounts configured on same machine one with Gerrit (Work Account) and another with GitHub(Personal).

I followed the Tutsplus You tube video mentioned in the answers from the below post:

[Multiple github accounts on the same computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860112/multiple-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer)

My Work account is already configured and working fine and following the global git config whereas for the personal work I have created a local config file and updated the User name and Email address by following below post:

[Git pushing to remote GitHub repository as wrong user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665337/git-pushing-to-remote-github-repository-as-wrong-user/6665231#6665231)

Now when I am trying to commit anything from the personal directory using Git Bash I am getting below error:

```
ERROR: Commit message is missing Identification: Please append the Identification: and issue ID relative to this commit into the commit message.
```

I do know that Identification is needed when I commit or push anything to my Gerrit account. So it means this is using or following the Gerrit based account config not my personal work account config(GitHub)

Now how can I use my personal work account linked with Git Hub with out bothering the Gerrit based GIT account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a post-commit hook set up to reject commits without an issue id, even in your personal work account repository.

Look in the `.git/hooks` directory for a `post-commit` (or `pre-push`) file, and delete it if present.

It may have been placed there by a `init.templatedir` global configuration -- try running `git config --list` to check.