# Specify an SSH key for git push for a given domain

Tags: git, ssh, gitolite

I have the following use case: I would like to be able to push to `git@git.company.com:gitolite-admin` using the private key of user `gitolite-admin`, while I want to push to `git@git.company.com:some_repo` using 'my own' private key. AFAIK, I can't solve this using `~/.ssh/config`, because the user name and server name are identical in both cases. As I mostly use my own private key, I have that defined in `~/.ssh/config` for `git@git.company.com`. Does anyone know of a way to override the key that is used for a single `git` invocation?

(Aside: gitolite distinguishes who is doing the pushing based on the key, so it's not a problem, in terms of access, ownership and auditing, that the user@server string is identical for different users.)

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565700/specify-private-ssh-key-to-use-when-executing-shell-command-with-or-without-ruby

Answer (score 845, accepted):

Even if the user and host are the same, they can still be distinguished in `~/.ssh/config`.  For example, if your configuration looks like this:

```
Host gitolite-as-alice
  HostName git.company.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/whoever/.ssh/id_rsa.alice
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host gitolite-as-bob
  HostName git.company.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/whoever/.ssh/id_dsa.bob
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Then you just use `gitolite-as-alice` and `gitolite-as-bob` instead of the hostname in your URL:

```
git remote add alice git@gitolite-as-alice:whatever.git
git remote add bob git@gitolite-as-bob:whatever.git
```

### Note

You want to include the option `IdentitiesOnly yes` to prevent the use of default ids. Otherwise, if you also have id files matching the default names, they will get tried first because unlike other config options (which abide by "first in wins") the `IdentityFile` option **appends** to the list of identities to try. See: https://serverfault.com/questions/450796/how-could-i-stop-ssh-offering-a-wrong-key/450807#450807

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I hadn't understood that you could freely choose an 'alias' for the Host specification in the ~/.ssh/config

Comment: Thanks too for this answer! One gotcha for me was that IdentityFile needs to be a full path (I only put id_rsa.rick as my argument to IdentityFile, and this failed). See the ssh_config(5) man page for other syntax for IdentityFile.

Comment: Thank you so much fo rthe clear and very helpful answer. I had tried to get this working for a while and gave up before with the assumption that the same user had to use the same id_rsa private key file.

Comment: The `git@` part in the remote is not necessary as it is given in the `User` line of the config.

Comment: You can use [`github-keygen`](https://github.com/dolmen/github-keygen) to easily add such a config for Github accounts.

Comment: I'm using windows with Git Bash. For the identity file line do I write: `IdentityFile ~davey/.ssh/id_rsa.davey` or `IdentityFile c:\Users\davey\.ssh\id_rsa.davey`?

Comment: I was struggling with this solution until I added another line containing `IdentitiesOnly yes` immediately after the line with `IdentityFile` for the host. It seems it was passing along multiple identities and one of those was blocked from accessing the host.

Comment: I had been constantly receiving `repository access denied` error with git commands while ssh commands worked. Adding the `IdentitiesOnly yes` line solved the issue.

Comment: Make sure that you've added your key to `ssh` using `ssh-add ~/.ssh/identity` (Linux, Mac), otherwise it won't be used even if it is specified in the IdentifyFile.

Comment: Do not forget to add the HostName to known_hosts : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363553/git-error-host-key-verification-failed-when-connecting-to-remote-repository#29380765

Comment: I posted a tweak to this answer below, using url rewriting in git, which removes the need to change remotes:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58550269/4907881

Comment: For the ones who their host is like github.com/CompanyName, they need to set like `Host github.com-companyname` and clone like `git clone git@github.com-companyname:companyname/reponame.git`

Comment: The examples in this post were confusing to me, therefore I struggled to get this to work. First of all if your trying to connect to github, make "host github.com" and "Hostname "github.com". Also "IdentityFile" is your PRIVATE key so put the full path "/home/yourusername/.ssh/id_ed25519" or "id_rsa" if using rsa. Looking at the example now I understand what they were trying to share, but it was confusing when first reading

Comment: @JustinLau, `IdentitiesOnly yes` breaks (remote) agent way of authentication. JFYI, Mark.

Comment: this didn't work for me (in my macbook) until i did this: `ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_id_file` i copied my key files from another computer.

Answer (score 195):

Configure your repository using `git config`

```
git config --add --local core.sshCommand 'ssh -i <PATH_TO_SSH_KEY>'
```

This applies to your *local repository* only.

Note: Use your private ssh key, **not** the one which by default ends with `.pub`.

Comment: I like this way because it works on a per repo basis and it's persistant

Comment: very good answer - and unlike editing the `~/.ssh/config` - this is repo-specific

Comment: Great answer! We are using it in jenkins job, so we need it only for a few seconds, so once it is done we are setting it off like this ```git config --unset --local core.sshCommand '<<ssh_token_path>>'```

Comment: Works on Windows as well - remember to replace the ` \ ` in the path with ` \\ `.

Comment: You may also clone a repo and give it the appropriate config before fetching files using the [`-c` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt--cltkeygtltvaluegt): `git clone -c core.sshCommand="ssh -i <<<PATH_TO_SSH_KEY>>>" git@host:repo.git`.

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski private. No need to abuse "?"

Answer (score 136):

You can utilize git environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`. Run this in your terminal under your git repository:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ~/.ssh/your_private_key' git submodule update --init
```

Replace `~/.ssh/your_private_key` with the path of ssh private key you wanna use. And you can change the subsequent git command (in the example is `git submodule update --init`) to others like `git pull`, `git fetch`, etc.

Comment: Full doc is at https://git-scm.com/docs/git#git-codeGITSSHcode; it needs a _recentish_ Git (>=2.3.*) though.

Comment: Thank you for a simple solution that does not require anything except setting one environment variable.

Comment: Note that your ~/.ssh/id_rsa (or whatever your default key is) will take precedence over the one you pass in via -i. So you really want to use GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ~/.ssh/your_private_key -o IdentitiesOnly=yes' to make it ignore other keys

Comment: how can you update git push? I couldn't find it in the documentation

Comment: Would be nice to create either bash or git aliases -- similar to sinelaw's answer but using this method instead of having to create scripts somewhere.

Comment: I needed to also force an empty config because my main one was overwriting the -i flag `-F /dev/null`

Answer (score 60):

An alternative approach to the [one offered above by Mark Longair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7927828/562906) is to use an alias that will run *any* git command, on *any* remote, with an alternative SSH key. The idea is basically to switch your SSH identity when running the git commands.

Advantages relative to the host alias approach in the other answer:

- Will work with *any* git commands or aliases, even if you can't specify the `remote` explicitly.
- Easier to work with many repositories because you only need to set it up once per client machine, not once per repository on each client machine.

I use a few small scripts and a git alias `admin`. That way I can do, for example:

```
git admin push
```

To push to the default remote using the alternative ("admin") SSH key. Again, you could use any command (not just `push`) with this alias. You could even do `git admin clone ...` to clone a repository that you would only have access to using your "admin" key.

**Step 1:** Create the alternative SSH keys, optionally set a passphrase in case you're doing this on someone else's machine.

**Step 2:** Create a script called “ssh-as.sh” that runs stuff that uses SSH, but uses a given SSH key rather than the default:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec ssh ${SSH_KEYFILE+-i "$SSH_KEYFILE"} "$@"
```

**Step 3:** Create a script called “git-as.sh” that runs git commands using the given SSH key.

```
#!/bin/bash
SSH_KEYFILE=$1 GIT_SSH=${BASH_SOURCE%/*}/ssh-as.sh exec git "${@:2}"
```

**Step 4:** Add an alias (using something appropriate for “PATH_TO_SCRIPTS_DIR” below):

```
# Run git commands as the SSH identity provided by the keyfile ~/.ssh/admin
git config --global alias.admin \!"PATH_TO_SCRIPTS_DIR/git-as.sh ~/.ssh/admin"
```

More details at: http://noamlewis.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/git-admin-an-alias-for-running-git-commands-as-a-privileged-ssh-identity/

Comment: Very nice answer.  Don't forget to add double quotes around `$@` -> `"$@"` to be safe.

Comment: @sinelaw Does this still work? I get Permission denied error all the time

Answer (score 54):

I've cribbed together and tested with github the following approach, based on reading other answers, which combines a few techniques:

- correct SSH config
- git URL re-writing

The advantage of this approach is, once set up, it doesn't require any additional work to get it right - for example, you don't need to change remote URLs or remember to clone things differently - the URL rewriting makes it all work.

`~/.ssh/config`

```
# Personal GitHub
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_id_rsa

# Work GitHub
Host github-work
  HostName github.com
  User git
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work_github_id_rsa

Host *
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

`~/.gitconfig`

```
[user]
    name = My Name
    email = personal@personal.email

[includeIf "gitdir:~/dev/work/"]
    path = ~/dev/work/.gitconfig

[url "github-work:work-github-org/"]
    insteadOf = git@github.com:work-github-org/
```

`~/dev/work/.gitconfig`

```
[user]
    email = work@work.email
```

As long as you keep all your work repos under ~/dev/work and personal stuff elsewhere, git will use the correct SSH key when doing pulls/clones/pushes to the server, and it will also attach the correct email address to all of your commits.

References:

- [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654115/4907881)
- [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860112/multiple-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer)

Comment: How does this work with cloning? `includeIf` should only work if there's a `.git` directory present I thought?

Comment: Wait I get it, it's the URL rewriting that takes care of that. This answer is incredibly useful!

Comment: Work but had to remove the `UseKeychain` line. For more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47455373/2037998

Answer (score 25):

**To use a specific key on the fly:**

```sh
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/id_ed25519 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -F /dev/null' git push origin c13_training_network
```

Explanation:

- local ENV var before doing the push
- `-i` specifies key
- `-F` forces an empty config so your global one doesn't overwrite this temporary command

Comment: This one actually helped in my case. The mere `ssh -i ...` wasn't enough, got to add these params as well

Comment: this should be the answer, as it was the only one that worked for me in 2023

Comment: Honestly, might just be easier to alias this command :) thx

Answer (score 17):

From git 2.10 upwards it is also possible to use the gitconfig sshCommand setting. [Docs state](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) :

> If this variable is set, git fetch and git push will use the specified command instead of ssh when they need to connect to a remote system. The command is in the same form as the GIT_SSH_COMMAND environment variable and is overridden when the environment variable is set.

An usage example would be: `git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i ~/.ssh/[insert_your_keyname]`

In some cases this doesn't work because ssh_config overriding the command, in this case try `ssh -i ~/.ssh/[insert_your_keyname] -F /dev/null` to not use the ssh_config.

Answer (score 13):

One Unix based systems (Linux, BSD, Mac OS X), the default identity is stored in the directory **$HOME/.ssh**, in 2 files:

`private key: $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
public key:  $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

When you use `ssh` without option `-i`, it uses the default private key to authenticate with remote system.

If you have another private key you want to use, for example ***$HOME/.ssh/deploy_key***, you have to use `ssh -i ~/.ssh/deploy_key ...`

It is annoying. You can add the following lines in to your ***$HOME/.bash_profile*** :

`ssh-add ~/.ssh/deploy_key
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

So each time you use `ssh` or `git` or `scp` (basically `ssh` too), you don't have to use option `-i` anymore.

You can add as many keys as you like in the file ***$HOME/.bash_profile***.

Answer (score 10):

Another alternative is to use [ssh-ident, to manage your ssh identities](https://github.com/ccontavalli/ssh-ident).

It automatically loads and uses different keys based on your current working directory, ssh options, and so on... which means you can easily have a work/ directory and private/ directory that transparently end up using different keys and identities with ssh.

Answer (score 8):

I am using Git Bash on Win7. The following worked for me.

Create a config file at ~/.ssh/config or c:/users/[your_user_name]/.ssh/config. In the file enter:

```
Host your_host.com
     IdentityFile [absolute_path_to_your_.ssh]\id_rsa
```

I guess the host has to be a URL and not just a "name" or ref for your host. For example,

```
Host github.com
     IdentityFile c:/users/[user_name]/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The path can also be written in /c/users/[user_name]/.... format

The solution provided by Giordano Scalzo is great too.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9149518/1738546

Answer (score 8):

If you already have default ssh key config but want to use different for specific repository then this should do the trick:

```
git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i ~/.ssh/github-personal -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -F /dev/null"
```

Answer (score 7):

One possibility to use `~/.ssh/config` is to use the `Match` restriction instead of the `Host` restriction. In particular `Match Exec` calls a shell command to decide whether to apply the declarations or not. In bash you could use the following command:

```
[ git@git.company.com:gitolite-admin = $(git config --get remote.origin.url)'' ]
```

This uses the bash `[` command to verify if two strings are equal. In this case it is testing if the string `git@git.company.com:gitolite-admin` matches the output that is obtained from the `$(git config --get remote.origin.url)''` command.

You can use any other command that identifies the repository that the shell is on. For this to work it is **important** to have the `$SHELL` variable defined to your shell, in my case `/bin/bash`. The full example would then be the following `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Match Exec "[ git@git.company.com:gitolite-admin = $(git config --get remote.origin.url)'' ]"
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitolite-admin
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  ForwardAgent no
  ForwardX11 no
  ForwardX11Trusted no

Match Exec "[ git@git.company.com:some_repo = $(git config --get remote.origin.url)'' ]"
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/yourOwnPrivateKey
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  ForwardAgent no
  ForwardX11 no
  ForwardX11Trusted no
```

In this example I assumed that `~/.ssh/yourOwnPrivateKey` contains your own private key and that `~/.ssh/gitolite-admin` contains the private key of the user `gitolite-admin`. I included the `IdentitiesOnly yes` declaration to make sure that only one key is offered to the git server, mentioned by [Mark Longair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223092/mark-longair). The other declarations are just standard ssh options for git.

You can add this configuration if you have several `some_repo` that you want to use with different keys. If you have several repositories at `git@git.company.com` and most of them use the `~/.ssh/yourOwnPrivateKey` it makes more sense to include this key as default for the host. In this case the `~/.ssh/config` would be:

```
Match Exec "[ git@git.company.com:gitolite-admin = $(git config --get remote.origin.url)'' ]"
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitolite-admin
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host git.company.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/yourOwnPrivateKey
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  ForwardAgent no
  ForwardX11 no
  ForwardX11Trusted no
```

Note that the order matters and the `Host git.company.com` restriction should appear after the `Match Exec` one or ones.

Comment: Thank you - this actually solves an issue that's been bugging me on VSCode - the Open On Github extensions would use the `Host` value in `Host gitolite-as-alice` (ignoring `HostName`) but this method avoids that problem!

Note that you can also use wildcard to match:

`Match Exec "[[ $(git config --get remote.origin.url)'' == 'git@github.com:YourOrganization'* ]]"`

Comment: Thanks you, I used second case and work with `Match Exec "[[ $(git config --get remote.origin.url)'' == 'git@github.com:YourOrganization'* ]]"`

Comment: Out of interest (I haven;t tried this approach yet though): why those single quotes are needed for? If this is plain `Bash` then the conditional can be as simple as this: `Match Exec "[[ $(git config --get remote.origin.url) == git@github.com:YourOrganization/* ]]"` (notice the trailing slash after the org name so it doesn't overlap with `YourOrganizationAnother`)

Comment: This is pretty awesome because you don't have to manipulate the actual git URL. However, it appears that this only works after the initial clone.  `git config --get remote.origin.url` doesn't return a value when `git clone` is run.

Answer (score 6):

As someone else mentioned, `core.sshCommand` config can be used to override SSH key and other parameters.

Here is an exmaple where you have an alternate key named `~/.ssh/workrsa` and want to use it for all repositories cloned under `~/work`.

1. Create a new `.gitconfig` file under `~/work`:

```
[core]
  sshCommand = "ssh -i ~/.ssh/workrsa"
```

2. In your global git config `~/.gitconfig`, add:

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/work/"]
  path = ~/work/.gitconfig
```

Answer (score 5):

For git to figure out, that it should use a different SSH keys, apart from changing your config file, as mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7927828/1306884
you may also need to purge and reload an active SSH identities.

On Mac, do the following:

```
ssh-add -D
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_one_that_you_want_to_use_instead
```

Using these two commands, and setting up the GIT URL to match the string defined in the `Host` of the ssh/config file, should allow you to use different SSH keys, for a different repositories.

For example for `Host work.github.com` use `work.github.com` as an URL when cloning your repository `git@work.github.com:your/repository.git`.

Answer (score 4):

If using Git's version of ssh on windows, the identity file line in the ssh config looks like

```
IdentityFile /c/Users/Whoever/.ssh/id_rsa.alice
```

where `/c` is for `c:`

To check, in git's bash do

```
cd ~/.ssh
pwd
```

Answer (score 3):

You might need to remove (or comment out) default Host configuration
[image: .ssh/config]

Answer (score 3):

Note: There's a way to apply the git config proposed in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62278407/7178540) for directories, not just at the repo level.

In my case, all projects were under the `~/work/` directory, so I updated my gitconfig as follows:

```
# ~/.gitconfig
...

[includeIf "gitdir:~/work/**"]
  path = "~/work/.gitconfig"
```

```
# ~/work/.gitconfig
[user]
  email = amr@work.com
  name = Amr Awad
  sshCommand = ssh -i ~/.ssh/work
```

and now all repos inside the `~/work/` directory use the work key `~/.ssh/work` without the need for configuring each repo separately.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simple approach :

**Default case**

-From your local root git folder.

-Check the current type of authentication method **HTTPS** or **SSH** of your local repository.

```
   git remote -v

 Example using HTTPS:
 origin  https://github.com/juantorres9/SQLite_crash_cours.git (fetch)
 origin  https://github.com/juantorres9/SQLite_crash_cours.git (push)
 Example using SSH:
 origin  git@github.com:juantorres9/SQLite_crash_cours.git (fetch)
 origin  git@github.com:juantorres9/SQLite_crash_cours.git (push)
```

-Set the new **authentication method** of your choice in case it's not already set.

```
 For setting SSH
 git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
 For setting HTTPS
 git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

-Check again in case you want to double check

```
 git remote -v;
```

-You are now able to use git push:fetch using your configured method.

```
git push origin master
```

**Note special cases:**

*Multiple SSH keys:*
If you have multiple SSH keys for different services (e.g., GitHub, GitLab) and you want to specify which key to use for a particular repository. This is common when you have different accounts on different platforms, the use the following command

`git config --local core.sshCommand 'ssh -i /path/to/your/private-key'`

*Using a non-default SSH key file:*
If your SSH key file is not in the default location (~/.ssh/id_rsa), and you want to specify its location use the same command above.

Last but not least , check updated official doc
https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories

Comment: In most cases this should work, but rarely cases where the git remote commands like push, pull, and fetch have no idea what your SSH private key is. In such a case, you might need to configure the key manually.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution @OgadaStanleyChinedu, indeed we might need to specify a non default private SSH key when contacting the remote repository, otherwise we could have authentication issues if the wrong key is used or not set . (update done )

Answer (score 2):

you most specified in the file config key ssh:

```
# Default GitHub user
Host one
 HostName gitlab.com
 User git
 PreferredAuthentications publickey
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key-one
 IdentitiesOnly yes

#two user
Host two
 HostName gitlab.com
 User git
 PreferredAuthentications publickey
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key-two
 IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting an SSH **permission denied Error** when running commands like *git push*, *pull*, or *fetch* even after you have copied your SSH public key to GitHub.

Use this:

```bash
git config --add --local core.sshCommand 'ssh -i /path-to-ssh-private-key'
```

E.g

```bash
git config --add --local core.sshCommand 'ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/github-key'
```

You're done!

Optionally you can verify your change with this:

```bash
git config --local --get core.sshCommand
```