# git + assembla + multiple ssh keys/multiple computers

Tags: git, ssh, assembla

I have multiple computers working on the same project, and I'm using a free assembla git repo account to manage all this.

In order to access the git repo, I need to generate unique SSH keys on each computer.
However, a computer might be working on other assembla projects as well, so there seems to be a conflict whenever I generate a new ssh key (like I have to keep replacing the id_rsa files).
Once I recreate the id_rsa files (and replace them) on a local machine, it loses access to the previous assembla git projects using the previously-generated ssh key.

I'm fairly new to the whole git business, and trying to learn as I go.

I found something that sounded like a solution to my problem:
"Different SSH keys for different projects"
http://www.assembla.com/spaces/breakoutdocs/wiki/Different_SSH_keys_for_different_projects

However, I don't understand how to do #1?  It says to "place somewhere in $PATH this script (let its name will be gitssh)", but I don't know what/where "$PATH" is?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!!

Comment: Why do you need to create unique ssh keys again? I have several work laptops and I have the same key on all of them. If a laptop get stolen I simply remove the key from the remote server (or request it if someone else is maintaining it.)

If Assembla requires a different key per project, try uploading the same key. If this doesn't let you  I would dump Assembla. And go with another provider or roll your own with Gitolite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create as many public/private ssh key as you want.
Simply don't use the default names `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`.

However, not using the default naming convention means ssh, by default, won't find your keys.
You need to define in your `~/.ssh` directory a config file, where you will indicate what private key to use:

```
Host myproject1
    HostName server1
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/project1.rsa
    User username
```

You can then push to `myproject1` if you have added `myproject1` as a remote.
See also "[Unable to Git-push master to Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922210/unable-to-git-push-master-to-github/922461#922461)" for ssh troubleshooting, and "[Specify an SSH key for git push without using `~/.ssh/config`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927750/specify-an-ssh-key-for-git-push-without-using-ssh-config/7927828#7927828)" for adding your ssh address as a remote.

You can add to the `~/.ssh/config` file as many address as you need, each one referring a private key that you can name as you want.

Comment: Had to play around with it a bit, but after going through the links you mentioned as well, got it to work!  Thank you!!

Comment: Another link I used for a reference: http://osxdaily.com/2011/04/05/setup-ssh-config-fie/ (to create the config file)