# Mercurial and Git custom SSH key location

Tags: git, mercurial, ssh, key

Exists there any way to define for each cloned repo the path of which SSH key pair it should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to define a `~/.ssh/config` file, in which you can declare different ssh names, with a custom full path name for the public/private key to use.

```
Host AHostName -- name you will use for the ssh address
User gituser
Hostname SSH IP address 
Port 1234 -- use this if you need custom ports
IdentityFile "path to your private ssh key"
```

From there, the ssh url of the repo can be:

```
AHostName:myrepo
```

See also:

- "[git + assembla + multiple ssh keys/multiple computers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8172628/6309)"
- "[How to work on personal GitHub repo from office computer whose SSH key is already added to a work related GitHub account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066895/how-to-work-on-personal-github-repo-from-office-computer-whose-ssh-key-is-alread/12066973#12066973)"

Comment: I think what you wrote defines a different ssh key for each host. I mean suppose that I have different repos on GitHub and each one of these should have a different ssh key pair

Comment: @Paris: that works for the same Host too: simply give "`Host`" a different name (it can be any name you want), even though "`Hostname`" will be `github.com` every time. That is exactly what is illustrated by my last link in the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066895/how-to-work-on-personal-github-repo-from-office-computer-whose-ssh-key-is-alread/12066973#12066973