# How does git remote pushing work?

Tags: git, github

How does the git remote push feature work? I'm trying to replicate the github's style of ssh pushing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub allows for ssh keys to be registered, and for an ssh kind of url to be used:

```
git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

If you want your own server to follow this, you need:

- an ssh daemon running, with git in its path.
- registering your public key in the git admin account (for instanced 'git') `authorized_keys` file (see "[Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server)"): beware of [the permission issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712443/creating-ssh-keys-for-gerrit-and-hudson/3712619#3712619).
- declaring on the client your private key in a [config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668278/mercurial-and-git-custom-ssh-key-location/12668477#12668477).

You will then be able to clone/push/pull your remote repo with the uri `yourserver:yourRepo` (which will refer to the '`yourServer`' entry of your config file)

As [Will Palmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1664755/will-palmer) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755002/how-does-git-remote-pushing-work/12757814#comment17238374_12757814), you can add to your git installation one **[authorization](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html)** framework called **[gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)**. See the [installation page](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/install.html), or my [own installation script for a local installation](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh) (in the same account than the '`git`' account)

Comment: a mention of gitolite would complete this answer

Comment: @WillPalmer mention added. I actually know gitolite well (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/gitolite/topusers)

Comment: Note: another ssh-based personal Git repo resembling to GitHub is GitLab: http://gitlabhq.com/