# deploying rails to heroku - unauthorized public key access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ssh, heroku

So I'm trying to deploy my app to heroku but it keeps giving me this error whenever I push to master:

`!  Your key with fingerprint cb:e1:5c:31:cd:6b:78:6e:30:ff:eb:11:e2:4b:2e:b3 is not authorized to access smooth-mountain-8970.`

I tried everything from generating new ssh keys to deleting everything and replacing the files. I even created a different username and tried uploading, but it keep giving me this error thinking that I want to upload to smooth-mountain when in fact, my app name is NOT smooth-mountain. Do you guys know what the problem might be?

Thanks.

Comment: This is what http://support.heroku.com is for.

Comment: Thats why I said I tried everything...

Comment: can you add the output of `git remote -v` in the project folder on your local machine.

Comment: do you want to share so it's useful for everyone else in the future? And mark the question as answered.

Comment: Yea, sorry about that. So you basically have to change the .config file of heroku and remove every remote access keys inside of it. That should fix it!

Comment: Which .config file, can you provide a full path -- thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`ssh-agent` (a program that holds private keys used for public key authentication) runs automatically since Mac OS X Leopard. To resolve your problem you must remove identities from the agent by issuing the following command.

```
ssh-add -d
```

Example:

```
> ssh-add -l 
1024 a3:d5:21:2d:50:ee:3e:af:1b:44:62:60:1d:e4:51:21 /Users/bart/.ssh/id_dsa (DSA)

> ssh-add -d 
Identity removed: /Users/bart/.ssh/id_dsa (/Users/bart/.ssh/id_dsa.pub)

> ssh-add -l 
The agent has no identities.
```

This will only remove the keys from this session temporarily. Personally, I don't mind doing this once in a while. However, if you would like disable ssh-agent permanently, see: [SSH Key Disable Caching](http://macends.com/blog/archive/2011/08/15/ssh-key-disable-caching.html)

Comment: In my case since I used a different key for Heroku (my id_rsa was already on file with my work account) I had to `ssh-add -d` then `ssh-add /Users/blah/.ssh/id_heroku`.

Answer (score 4):

After I rename my app at Heroku.com, I had the problem:

```
 !  Your key with fingerprint xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx is not authorized to access smooth-rain-5917.

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I was try almost everything ... as @Nosayr Yassin, said ...

I don't have any *.config* file, but I found the wrong reference at

*`my_app_root_dir/.git/config`*

it's contains

```
[remote "heroku"]
        url = git@heroku.com:smooth-rain-5917.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

I changed for:

```
[remote "heroku"]
        url = git@heroku.com:my_new_app_name.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

Then, run agian

```
git push heroku master
```

and that's it, I finally can re-deploy my app again ...

thks for all your tips :P

Rgds
iVieL

edited: btw, I running on OSX Lion :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case,

```
heroku keys
```

Did show me my correct key, but I still couldn't push to Heroku.

This is what worked for me:

```
ssh-add -d
heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_heroku.pub
```

That is, it worked for me yesterday, but today... it did not.

This is what worked today, thanks to help from my Unix-master boss:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa*
cd ~/.ssh
ls -l
chmod 600 id_rsa*
chmod 644 *.pub
ls -l
ssh-add id_rsa
ssh-add id_rsa_heroku
cd -
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved this kind of problem just by typing in local shell

```
heroku accounts:set accountname
```

where *accountname* is the name of the account that holds the Heroku app. After that *git push heroku master* works fine. Didn't have to do anything else.

Looks like many have run into this problem with multiple accounts, so I thought I'd share this. I'm myself managing multiple accounts (on a single machine) of which each has multiple apps deployed. I've installed the heroku-accounts plugin for Heroku CLI. (https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts)

Answer (score 1):

I found an easier solution via [Heroku Devcenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys/). Here's what I did to get it working properly.

> ssh-keygen -t rsa

It will generate the public/private rsa key pair. If you already have one then pass n for no.

> heroku keys:add

It will find existing public key and upload the SSH public key.

That's it. It was that easy.