# multiple heroku accounts not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, ssh

I'll be very detailed, as I followed the advice on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786564/cannot-push-to-heroku-because-key-fingerprint) and it didn't work.

I'm on Mac OS X 10.7 trying to make two heroku accounts work. Let's call these accounts `first` and `second`

To start clean, I removed the keys in `~.ssh/`, run
`heroku keys:remove` on both accounts to get rid of existing keys, and run ssh-add -D to remove existing entries (in other words: ~.ssh/ is empty, except for known_hosts; `heroku keys` says I have no keys, and ssh-add -L says there are no entries.

I `heroku login` into the first account and I run these:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "first@example.com" -f  ~/.ssh/id_rsa_first
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_first
heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_first.pub
```

then I `heroku logout` and `heroku login` into the second account and I run these:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "second@example.com" -f  ~/.ssh/id_rsa_second
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_second
heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_second.pub
```

In both cases I note down the key fingerprints, which I'll call `fingerprint_first` and `fingerprint_second`.

Now I `heroku login` to `first` and `git push heroku master` works fine, then `heroku login` to `second` on a second app and `git push heroku master` fails, with the error

```
!  Your key with fingerprint fingerprint_first is not authorized to access second-app-name.
```

If I remove that from the ssh list with `ssh-add -d ~/.ssh/id_rsa_first`, then `git push heroku master` works on the second app, but now if I go back to the first app and `heroku login` to the first account, `git push heroku master` of course fails.

Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end, [this answered it](https://getsatisfaction.com/heroku/topics/can_i_use_different_heroku_credentials_on_different_projects).

I restarted from scratch, removing all keys, and added [David Dollar's plugin heroku-accounts](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts)

Now it works, and I don't even need to log out/in when I switch projects, as I can set a Heroku account on each project directory.

Comment: David's plugin now gets automatically uninstalled with the latest heroku cli `Uninstalling deprecated ddollar/heroku-accounts plugin... done` :(

Comment: Heroku have forked and taken over the project.

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-accounts

To install you'll need to follow the instructions above.

Importantly you need to manually set the account to be in use.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem had by another stackoverflow user;

[Cannot push to Heroku because key fingerprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786564/cannot-push-to-heroku-because-key-fingerprint)

As well as:

[Why is my key w/ fingerprint not authorized when I try to push latest changes to Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049905/why-is-my-key-w-fingerprint-not-authorized-when-i-try-to-push-latest-changes-to)