# Heroku (tried everything that I can find resources to)

Tags: ruby, git, heroku

I have tried pretty much everything I can think of to just be able to login to heroku. The only thing left I could think of is run as a new user on my computer (which is a mac). And then see if it's something that is messed up with my config.

At one point I could but then I had conflicts with an old work email it was using, although I was able to use heroku, i couldn't get to that email anymore.

So I tried to start as if I just installed heroku and I started a new account, and I tried the standard setup then I went to this: [Cannot push to Heroku because key fingerprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786564/cannot-push-to-heroku-because-key-fingerprint)

And nothing worked, I just keep getting Authentication failed. Any Ideas?

Just to recap:

I've

1. deleted the ~/.ssh directory and added github then my heroku key with the add:key function
2. tried just making a new user account and reinstalling tool belt, and going through a normal setup flow.
3. And tried various stackoverflow solutions the latest being referenced above.

-- What I'd like to do isn't special, it's just to have one user account on my computer. Is there an issue if your user account email is the same as your github email? I've tried it with and without and all I get is "Authentication failed." again and again.

Plleeeassee help.

tyttytyty