# Setting up Heroku from a clean slate

Tags: git, heroku, key, fingerprint

I keep running into issues with "Your key with fingerprint ... is not authorized to access" errors when I try to run `git push heroku master`. I've tried multiple combinations of removing the key and adding it again. I've viewed multiple stackoverflow [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786564/cannot-push-to-heroku-because-key-fingerprint/8803103#8803103) and tried all of the suggestions. Everything i've read makes me think that I have old accounts that I don't know about on this machine. Is there any way to view all of the accounts on this machine? Or is there a way to unstall heroku and start with a clean slate?

Comment: How many keys are in your ssh public key file?

Comment: @Fred only the one. I've deleted, renamed, than uploade the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files too. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use `heroku keys` to manage your ssh_keys that you have associated with heroku. Check out the documentation on the heroku devcenter for more help. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys