# Deploy an app to heroku fail because of key not authorized

Tags: git, heroku, ssh

When I am executing :

```
 git push heroku master
```

I got the following:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-0-92:~/node-js-sample$ git push heroku master

 !  Your key with fingerprint XXXXXXXXXX is not authorized to access radiant-ocean-5431.
```

I have only one ssh-key registered on my heroku account, and only one app.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-37-201:~/node-js-sample$ heroku apps
=== My Apps
radiant-ocean-5431
thawing-bayou-7424
```

This is what `ssh-add -l` outputs:

```
2048 AAAAAAAAAAA /Users/mylocaluser/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
2048 BBBBBBBBBBB /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa_heroku (RSA)
```

`git remote show heroku` fails too

I tried to delete and create again my keys but without any success.
I have also deleted manually most of my keys on herokus, without any success.

I have also followed this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786564/cannot-push-to-heroku-because-key-fingerprint

I have an alias for my user when I am using ssh, could it be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct heroku repo url `git remote show heroku`?

Comment: git remote show heroku fails too, I edited my question.

Comment: are you sure you're logged into the correct account? Does `heroku auth:whoami` show you the output you would expect to when you are adding your keys?

Comment: heroku auth:whoami gives me my login email address yes. I tried again from sratch without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ssh-add -l` was not listing my public key on the **remote machine**, because it was not existing.

**Running `ssh-keygen` fixed the issue.**

Answer (score 1):

Need to manually delete openssl.cnf... find the file on your machine and rename it to something else....
[Heroku client internal error. Unable to verify certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268517/heroku-client-internal-error-unable-to-verify-certificate)