# Heroku client internal error. Unable to verify certificate

Tags: heroku

Heroku keys, heroku run rake etc seem to be having issues
Anyone else having this issue? / know how to get around it ?
Thanks !

Trace--
!    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

```
Error:       Unable to verify certificate, please set `Excon.defaults[:ssl_ca_path] = path_to_certs`, `Excon.defaults[:ssl_ca_file] = path_to_file`, or `Excon.defaults[:ssl_verify_peer] = false` (less secure). (Excon::Errors::SocketError)
Backtrace:   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/excon-0.25.0/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:69:in `connect'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/excon-0.25.0/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:69:in `initialize'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/excon-0.25.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:365:in `new'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/excon-0.25.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:365:in `socket'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/excon-0.25.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:105:in `request_call'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/excon-0.25.0/lib/excon/middlewares/mock.rb:42:in `request_call'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/excon-0.25.0/lib/excon/middlewares/instrumentor.rb:22:in `request_call'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/excon-0.25.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:15:in `request_call'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/excon-0.25.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:15:in `request_call'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/excon-0.25.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:244:in `request'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-api-0.3.13/lib/heroku/api.rb:76:in `request'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-api-0.3.13/lib/heroku/api/login.rb:9:in `post_login'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.39.4/lib/heroku/auth.rb:80:in `api_key'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.39.4/lib/heroku/auth.rb:189:in `ask_for_credentials'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.39.4/lib/heroku/auth.rb:221:in `ask_for_and_save_credentials'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.39.4/lib/heroku/auth.rb:84:in `get_credentials'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.39.4/lib/heroku/auth.rb:74:in `password'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.39.4/lib/heroku/auth.rb:17:in `api'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.39.4/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:40:in `api'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.39.4/lib/heroku/command/keys.rb:27:in `index'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.39.4/lib/heroku/command.rb:206:in `run'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.39.4/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.39.4/bin/heroku:17:in `<top (required)>'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
             /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'

Command:     heroku keys
Version:     heroku-gem/2.39.4 (x86_64-darwin11.4.0) ruby/1.9.3
```

Answer (score 10):

Running 'heroku  update' in terminal fixed this for me.

Comment: This fixed it for me as well. Much rather do this than rename files etc.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem briefly on Mac OS X when I had version 2.39.4 of the heroku gem installed.  I uninstalled it and allowed the Heroku toolbelt to be the provider of my heroku executable again, and although I had to go through "heroku auth:login" and "heroku keys:add " again, it now works as expected.

N.B. The heroku gem is still required on my Vagrant Heroku Ubuntu VM, of course.

Answer (score 5):

Need to manually delete openssl.cnf... find the file on your machine and rename it to something else.... bug in the latest excon release....

Comment: I deleted openssl.cnf in mingw32 folder and everything started working.

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to fix this by deleting openssl.conf.

However, I was able to fix this by installing the heroku toolbelt and then deleting ALL old installations of the heroku gem.

```
macbook:~ johnnygoodman$ gem uninstall heroku

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. heroku-2.35.0
 2. heroku-2.39.4
 3. All versions
> 3
Successfully uninstalled heroku-2.35.0
Remove executables:
    heroku

macbook:~ johnnygoodman$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: 
Password (typing will be hidden):
Authentication successful.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and renamed the openssl.cnf file on my machine, as user2515011 recommends above, and it's worked.

To be honest, I don't know why this has worked, or if it has left me vulnerable elsewhere. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm unable to duplicate this on my macbook air. I wonder if perhaps it relates to rvm. What version are you using? It looks as though it used to package openssl: https://rvm.io/packages/openssl (but probably shouldn't any longer, and at least on my machine using the packaged versions works well). Could you try following the advice from that page and running `rvm autolibs enable` and trying again?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem and none of the suggestions were working for me.

It turns out when trying to fix a different problem I had set an environment variable to set my SSL Certificate location to be in the RailsInstaller directory.

I recommend checking for any suspicious environment variables if none of the above answers are helping you.