# Set up Heroku in Windows

Tags: windows, heroku

I am new to Heroku. I followed the tutorials from Heroku website to set up Heroku in Windows. I installed the  Heroku Toolbelt. When I run the command `$ heroku login`, and type in the email and password, I get the following error:

```
Owner@OWNER-PC ~
$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: qwe
Password (typing will be hidden):
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

Error:       Unable to verify certificate, please set `Excon.defaults[:ssl_ca_path] = path_to_certs`, `Excon.defaults[:ssl_ca_file] = path_to_file`, or `Excon.defaults[:ssl_verify_peer] = false` (less secure). (Excon::Errors::SocketError)
Backtrace:   C:/Users/Owner/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/excon-0.22.1/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:55:in `connect'
             C:/Users/Owner/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/excon-0.22.1/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:55:in `initialize'
             C:/Users/Owner/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/excon-0.22.1/lib/excon/connection.rb:367:in `new'
             C:/Users/Owner/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/excon-0.22.1/lib/excon/connection.rb:367:in `socket'
             C:/Users/Owner/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/excon-0.22.1/lib/excon/connection.rb:105:in `request_call'
             C:/Users/Owner/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/excon-0.22.1/lib/excon/middlewares/mock.rb:42:in `request_call'
             C:/Users/Owner/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/excon-0.22.1/lib/excon/middlewares/instrumentor.rb:22:in `request_call'
             C:/Users/Owner/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/excon-0.22.1/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:15:in `request_call'
             C:/Users/Owner/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/excon-0.22.1/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:15:in `request_call'
             C:/Users/Owner/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/excon-0.22.1/lib/excon/connection.rb:246:in `request'
             C:/Users/Owner/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/heroku-api-0.3.11/lib/heroku/api.rb:76:in `request'
             C:/Users/Owner/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/heroku-api-0.3.11/lib/heroku/api/login.rb:9:in `post_login'
             C:/Users/Owner/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/auth.rb:80:in `api_key'
             C:/Users/Owner/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/auth.rb:189:in `ask_for_credentials'
             C:/Users/Owner/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/auth.rb:221:in `ask_for_and_save_credentials'
             C:/Users/Owner/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/auth.rb:84:in `get_credentials'
             C:/Users/Owner/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/auth.rb:41:in `login'
             C:/Users/Owner/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/auth.rb:31:in `login'
             C:/Users/Owner/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command.rb:206:in `run'
             C:/Users/Owner/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
             c:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku:29:in `<main>'

Command:     heroku login
Version:     heroku/toolbelt/2.39.4 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.3
```

It doesn't matter what email address I typed in, the error is still the same.

I've tried searching it for similar issues, but don't seem to find a solution to fix my problem. Please help me, thank you very much!!

Comment: Looks like an issue here, mentioned as well: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/245

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several other references to this issue:

- [Heroku client internal error. Unable to verify certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268517/heroku-client-internal-error-unable-to-verify-certificate)
- https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/245

Some solutions that others reported to have worked:

1. `[sudo] gem install certified`

   add to gemfile : `gem 'certified'`

   `bundle install`
2. try adding the /certs folder to your /lib directory from https://github.com/stevegraham/certified
3. Try setting HEROKU_SSL_VERIFY to disable `$ HEROKU_SSL_VERIFY=disable` heroku logs
4. Possibly try uninstalling the gem, and instead downloading/installing the toolbelt from https://toolbelt.heroku.com

Comment: Hi, I did tried everything. I downloaded the toolbelt from Heroku.com. And that's the error i got.

Comment: $ gem install certified
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'certified' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: I remember I successfully certified before, but the result was the same

Comment: Odd, try installing certs on your system here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat)

Comment: option 3, set HEROKU_SSL_VERIFY to disable, worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same problem and none of the suggestions were working for me.

It turns out when trying to fix a different problem I had set an environment variable to set my SSL Certificate location to be in the RailsInstaller directory.

I recommend checking for any suspicious environment variables if none of the above answers are helping you.

Answer (score 1):

I too had this problem. The following worked for me:

1. [downloaded toobelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) and re-installed it (even without uninstalling the previous installation)
2. ran `heroku login` to re-establish the login

Simple as it may sound, it solved my certificate problem :)