# Getting error messages using heroku cli; like ➜ ~ heroku apps

Tags: heroku

I'm getting the following error with Heroku cli:

➜  ~ heroku apps

!    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

```
Error:       hostname "manager-api.heroku.com" does not match the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError) (Excon::Errors::SocketError)
Backtrace:   /Users/ianoconnor/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/ssl.rb:139:in `post_connection_check'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gem uninstall heroku
```

and then

```
gem install heroku
```

is one way this can be solved.

Please see many other possible solutions for this duplicate question: [Heroku client internal error. Unable to verify certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268517/heroku-client-internal-error-unable-to-verify-certificate)