# please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists

Tags: heroku, key, git-push

Hello I am following the `ruby.railstutorial`. I ran these commands

```
heroku keys/add
```

then

```
C:\Users\Pierre-Henri\Desktop\Mon bazar\Ruby\code\omrails>git remote add heroku
git@heroku.com:omrails.git
```

each it works and also finally :

> C:\Users\Pierre-Henri\Desktop\Mon bazar\Ruby\code\omrails> git push heroku master

and it spits out this error:

```
 !  Your key with fingerprint 22:8f:57:8b:d2:2e:7e:f4:a4:0d:e6:cb:f0:51:27:3d is
 not authorized to access omrails.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

what does that mean?

Comment: Please refer to this thread for information.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786564/cannot-push-to-heroku-because-key-fingerprint?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a git repository? Create it using `git init` and then commit some files.