# Cloning heroku app issues - fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: heroku, ssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to clone a heroku application, but keep getting the error :

```
 !  Your key with fingerprint XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is not authorized to access <APP NAME>.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have tried to follow the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9149518/79465, but nothing helps.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: it looks that your ssh keys are not set correctly what do you get when you do `heroku apps`