# Maven release git-push "Host key verification failed."

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

When I am trying to have *jenkins* run a `mvn -B release:prepare` it gets to the point where it is to `push` changes to git, but fails with `Host key verification failed.` This is a local git repository.

At this time, *jenkins* is run as `root`. SSH keys have been created for `root` and they have been added appropriately to the git user's `authorized_keys`.

In fact, I can *ssh* to the build machine, `su` to `root` run
`git clone git@localhost:my-project.git`
clone successfully, create a branch and push that branch to `origin` successfully.

Another strange thing is *jenkins* can clone the repository successfully before `mvn release:prepare` is run.

When it tries to `push`, it gives the `Host key verification failed.` error.

I have dumbed the build down to be 1 execution step

```
git clone git@localhost:my-project.git
mvn -B release:prepare
```

Before responding, please don't suggest the git plugin or *maven release plugin*. These can't be installed.

Comment: further, after the build, jenkins run a whoami command and it shows as 'root'

Comment: [Git error: "Host Key Verification Failed" when connecting to remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363553/git-error-host-key-verification-failed-when-connecting-to-remote-repository)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.

While `localhost` was added to roots ~/.ssh/known_hosts file the actual IP of the box was not. Adding the public IP of the box to known_hosts resolved the issue.