# Jenkins Host key verification failed

Tags: jenkins

I have a problem with **jenkins**, setting "git", shows the following error:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h https://person@bitbucket.org/person/projectmarket.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: fatal: Authentication failed
```

I have tested with **ssh**:

```
git@bitbucket.org:person/projectmarket.git
```

This is error:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:person/projectmarket.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I've also done these steps with "SSH key".

Login under Jenkins

```
sudo su jenkins
```

Copy your github key to Jenkins .ssh folder

```
cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github* /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/
```

Rename the keys

```
mv id_rsa_github id_rsa
mv id_rsa_github.pub id_rsa.pub
```

but still not working **git** repository in **jenkins**.

thanks by help!.

Comment: Related: [Git error: “Host Key Verification Failed” when connecting to remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13363553/55075)

Comment: no jenkins user existing

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Change to the `jenkins` user and run the command manually:

```
git ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:person/projectmarket.git HEAD
```

You will get the standard SSH warning when first connecting to a new host via SSH:

```
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (207.223.240.181)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Type `yes` and press Enter.  The host key for `bitbucket.org` will now be added to the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file and you won't get this error in Jenkins anymore.

Comment: show this:
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: Right, but that's an entirely different error.  Now you have to go add your public key to the repository over at bitbucket.org.

Comment: See step 6 here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git

Comment: Please accept the answer if the error message went away.  Judging by your comment, you are no longer getting the 'host key verification failed' error.  The error you're now getting is an authentication error.  You have to add your public key on your bitbucket.org repository.

Comment: I had to do this and restart my Jenkins app server (Glassfish) for this to work.

Comment: +1 for "worksforme", had the exact same problem. Created id_rsa for the proper user, chmod-ed to jenkins, added the public key, still did not work. Trying git as sudo -u jenkins yielded the knonwn_hosts file, fixing the problem.

Comment: This worked for me for Jenkins.app on OS X, but you don't need to change to the jenkins user. Just run it from your own user account

Comment: You need to run it as the user that is running Jenkins.  On most systems, one typically runs it as a separate user (e.g. a 'jenkins' user).  Hence, you would need to switch to that user to ensure that the address for bitbucket.org is added to ~/.ssh/known_hosts.

Comment: What this line means:

Change to the jenkins user and run the command manually:

I am window OS user.

Comment: Modifying the known_hosts file to work for bitbucket worked for me when I had the same error using mercurial

Comment: @CamHart Yes, you can edit it manually, if you know the server's key.  The instruction provided updates known_hosts for you.

Comment: did you know you can use `ssh-keyscan` for this? example: `ssh-keyscan -t rsa bitbucket.org >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: An important addition: this holds true *even if you run the job as a 'specific user'*! Despite indicating that the job runs as that user, the known hosts from the jenkins user are used to validate outgoing ssh connections.

Comment: what is the jenkins password?

Comment: I have a similar requirement. If i"m running `git ls-remote ..` command through a script, how can i enter `yes` to the standard SSH warning from the script itself.

Comment: It asks for a password that i don't know, it's not any of the passwords for git users, jenkins users, or anything else.

Comment: @Owl The "git ls-remote" command?  Then you haven't set up public key authentication properly.  You need to associate the public key of the jenkins user (or whatever account is running Jenkins) with your Bitbucket account. See the Bitbucket docs for details -- I don't use that service, but the same priniciple is true no matter what Git service you're using.

Comment: @ctc i ended up solving this by making a ssh key on the jenkins client and putting it into the keystore in the git server side, this solved my password issues.

Comment: @Owl Yep, that's the right approach.  Glad you got it working.

Comment: I get this error
"Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts)" after typing "yes", any idea what can be the issue?

Comment: @Avishay28 Check the permissions on the file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts as well as the permissions on the .ssh directory.  Make sure the jenkins user has access to write to the file.

Comment: I had to go ahead and add a `known_hosts` file in  the `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh` folder. This issue was throwing me off because I was not 100% if the configuration command was running on a Node or on my main Jenkins Server. Once I did that (make sure the file is owned by the jenkins user) my Pipeline config worked as expected.

Comment: Thank you! If you don't have the server in known_hosts yet, is there a way to add it in the Jenkins web UI? This only seems to happen on newer Jenkins servers, so maybe it auto accepted the host's keys if they were unknown on the previous ones that I had setup.

Answer (score 69):

Jenkins is a service account, it doesn't have a shell by design. It is generally accepted that service accounts. shouldn't be able to log in interactively.

To resolve "Jenkins Host key verification failed", do the following steps. I have used mercurial with jenkins.

1. Execute following commands on terminal

```
$ sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins
```

provide password

2. Generate public private key using the following command:

```
ssh-keygen
```

you can see output as ::

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair. 
Enter file in which to save the key (/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again:
```

3. Press Enter --> Do not give any passphrase--> press enter

```
Key has been generated
```

4. go to --> cat /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
5. Copy key from id_rsa.pub
6. Exit from bash
7. `ssh@yourrepository`
8. `vi .ssh/authorized_keys`
9. Paste the key
10. exit
11. Manually login to mercurial server

Note: Pls do manually login otherwise jenkins will again give error "host verification failed"

12. once manually done, Now go to Jenkins and give build

Enjoy!!!

Good Luck

Comment: WHAT password is requested here?

Answer (score 33):

Or you can use:

`ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no host`

This will be insecure (man in the middle attacks) but easiest solution.

The better way to do that is to generate correct mappings between host and ip address, so `ssh` will not complain:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for domain in "github.com" "bitbucket.org"; do
    sed -i "/$domain/d" ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    line=$(ssh-keyscan $domain,`nslookup $domain | awk '/^Address: / { print $2 ; exit }'`)
    echo $line >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
done
```

Excerpt from [gist](https://gist.github.com/FelikZ/94e67967b3b22e61d94ee68b184702d4).

---

note, the above can be also done directly from terminal:

```
domain=github.com
sed -i "/$domain/d" ~/.ssh/known_hosts
line=$(ssh-keyscan $domain,`nslookup $domain | awk '/^Address: / { print $2 ; exit }'`)
echo $line >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: This opens you up to potential MITM attacks.

Comment: You can add -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no and connect once, which will add the host to the known_hosts file (same as when you ssh on the command line and type yes to add the key to the known_hosts file) and then remove this option after that.

Comment: Domain lookups are dicey because the hosts may be running on a cluster. The machine you got a minute ago could be a different box the next minute.

Answer (score 26):

Under `Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security` there is:

[image]

btw. No Verification is for sure not the best option.

Comment: nice. Just for others sake, this setting can be found under 'Manage Jenkins' > 'Configure Global Security'

Comment: This was the only answer that worked with Jenkins installed in Windows Server and Github with private repository.

Comment: I believe that this is the correct way to supply the known-hosts key to Jenkins. It does not require logging into the host via ssh, remains portable (if you move your jenkins instance) and retains visibility from within Jenkins. - I had to make sure when I setup the job that I use "ssh" and not the "https" URI

Comment: "Configure Global Security" has been renamed Manage Jenkins > "Security" in newer versions. Also, "Accept first connection" is an option in the dropdown that worked for me.

Comment: known_hosts file on the server worked until I upgraded Jenkins to  2.426.3 this AM and one of our agents would refuse to connect to bitbucket.  Provided bitbucket keys in the Manually Provided Keys option and GitSCM seems to work now

Answer (score 8):

Had same problem, i fix it like that :

reset permission on id_rsa* only for current user no group no other

```
chmod o-rwx ~/.ssh/id*
chmod G-rwx ~/.ssh/id*

ls -lart ~/.ssh/


-rw-------  1 jenkins nogroup  398 avril  3 09:34 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------  1 jenkins nogroup 1675 avril  3 09:34 id_rsa
```

And clear ~/.ssh/know_hosts

Now Connect as jenkins

```
sudo su jenkins
```

Try the jenkins commands

```
git ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:user/project.git HEAD
```

If no problem appears, now jenkins will be able to connect the repo (for me ^^ at least)

Comment: The above command(chmod G-rwx ~/.ssh/id*) for changing the group permission failed. The below worked as desired.                      chmod g-rwx ~/.ssh/id*

Answer (score 8):

As for the workaround (e.g. Windows slave), define the following environment variable in global properties:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
```

[image: Jenkins, Global properties, Environment variables, GIT_SSH_COMMAND]

Note: If you don't see the option, you probably need [*EnvInject* plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject) for it.

Answer (score 4):

1. Login as jenkins using: `sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins`
2. `git clone` the desired repo which causes the key error
3. It will ask you to add the key by showing Yes/No (enter yes or y)

*That's it!*

You can now re-run the Jenkins job.

Comment: No, it just asks for a password, and i tried the jenkins password and the git password and it doesn't accept either.

Answer (score 3):

using https://bitbucket.org/YYYY/XX.git

you shoud delete username@

Answer (score 3):

- Make sure we are not editing any of the default sshd_config properties to skip the error
- Host Verification Failed - Definitely a missing entry of hostname in `known_hosts` file
- Login to the server where the process is failing and do the following:

  1. Sudo to the user running the process
  2. `ssh-copy-id destinationuser@destinationhostname`
  3. It will prompt like this for the first time, say yes and it will also ask password for the first time:

     ```
     The authenticity of host 'sample.org (205.214.640.91)' can't be established.
     RSA key fingerprint is 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40.
     Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? *yes*
     ```

     Password prompt ? *give password*
  4. Now from the server where process is running, do `ssh destinationuser@destinationhostname`. It should login without a password.

     **Note:** Do not change the default permissions of files in the user's *.ssh* directory, you will end up with different issues

Comment: in step 3, it might be the case that, you are prompted with key already exist in the file, but you should continue this 4 steps  and if you can login without password from jenkins user, than you are all set.

Comment: Missing .pub file for jenkins user.

Answer (score 3):

Best way you can just use your "git url" in 'https" URL format in the Jenkinsfile or wherever you want.

`git url: 'https://github.com/jglick/simple-maven-project-with-tests.git'`

Answer (score 3):

Copy host keys from both bitbucket and github:

```
ssh root@deployserver 'echo "$(ssh-keyscan -t rsa,dsa bitbucket.org)" >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts'
ssh root@deployserver 'echo "$(ssh-keyscan -t rsa,dsa github.com)" >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts'
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue and it turned out the problem was that the jenkins service wasn't being run as the jenkins user. So running the commands as the jenkins user worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

In Jenkins, you can manage strict host checking behavior in "Global security" parameters

[image: jenkins screenshot]

Comment: Just be aware that disabling strict host checking makes you vulnerable to Man-In-The-Middle (mitm) attacks

Answer (score 2):

**SSH**

If you are trying it with SSH, then the **Host key Verification** error can come due to several reasons.Follow these steps to overcome all the reasons.

1. Set the Environment variable as **HOME** and provide the address as the root directory of **.ssh** folder. e.g:- If your .ssh is kept inside **Name** folder. 
    C:/Users/Name.
2. Now make sure that the public SSH key is being provided in the repository link also. Either it is github or bitbucket or any other.
3. Open git bash. And try cloning the project from the repository. This will help in adding your repository URL in the known_host file, which is being auto created in the .ssh folder.
4. Now open jenkins and create a new job. Then click on configure.
5. provide the cloning URL in Source code management under Git. The URL should be start with git@github.com/......... or ssh://proje........
6. Under the Credential you need to add the username and password of your repository form which you are cloning the project. Select that credential.
7. And now apply and save the configuration.
8. Bingo! Start building the project. I hope now you will not get any Host Key verification error!

Answer (score 2):

There is a safe and (relative easy) way to accomplish this, which should also work if you have separate worker nodes/clouds (like docker/kubernetes).

Maintaining the keys can also be added to the Jenkins configuration as code so you can maintain it in code for easier redeployment.

### Adding host keys to Jenkins configuration

- First go to a console and execute `ssh-keyscan -H your_git_server.url`
- Copy the output of that command
- Then navigate to *https://YOUR_JENKINS_URL/manage/configureSecurity/*
- Scroll down to **Git Host Key Verification Configuration**
- Paste the output of the command into the window. it should look like this:

[image: Example output]

Both [bitbucket](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-ssh-and-two-step-verification/) and github have pages about their keys and servers. Read them and ensure that you are adding the proper keys and not some random keys

### Getting the ssh-keyscan via your Jenkins installation

If you for some reason do not have `ssh-keyscan`, you can go to the script console ( *https://YOUR_JENKINS_URL/manage/script* ) and paste in the following script:

```groovy
def sout = new StringBuilder(), serr = new StringBuilder()
def proc = 'ssh-keyscan -H bitbucket.org'.execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
println "copy this to jenkins>\n$sout"
//println "err> $serr"
```

[image: script output]

Answer (score 1):

Try

ssh-keygen -R hostname

-R hostname Removes all keys belonging to hostname from a known_hosts file. This option is useful to delete hashed hosts

Answer (score 1):

Use ssh-keyscan should be much more easier:

```
ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

This command will put all required hosts to `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. You will need to run this command inside your Jenkins machine. You can also create a job and put that command into the "Execute shell" section of the Configure of that job and then execute the job.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I had the ssh key setup in both the server and github. I can run `ssh -T git@github.com` without problem. When I manually run the following command, I had no problem.

```
git ls-remote -h git@github.com:jessy-3/vanilla.git HEAD
```

But when I configure it with Jenkins, I got the problem.
It worked when "Host Key Verification Strategy" in "Configure Global Security" set to "No verification" but not on "Known hosts file".

The final solution is to go to `cd ~/.ssh` then `chmod 644 privatekeyfile`.

Answer (score 1):

## Secure and easy way to add host keys

The host keys need to be added either to .ssh/known_hosts file or into the Jenkins GUI. The latter is shown in this answer.

Error message from Jenkins 2.426.1:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h -- git@bitbucket.org:youruser/yourrepository.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: No ED25519 host key is known for bitbucket.org and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The main part is:

```
Host key verification failed.
```

### 1. Get the host keys

This can be done on any machine, your local laptop or any server.

#### For bitbucket.org

```
ssh-keyscan -H bitbucket.org

# bitbucket.org:22 SSH-2.0-conker_95dc3707a5 3dcc5f8f2ee6
|1|sm0rsQ/wpQFuBXLDjrlpszP5LuE=|639nVsWhoeVMHJ8x+KO8cDLiLfM= ssh-rsa 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
# bitbucket.org:22 SSH-2.0-conker_95dc3707a5 75a947814076
|1|ENd8Gydk8INYO3qW4KdJU5jASUQ=|QMIjWYV2MPuaXELEvUnaF8CkCaU= ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBPIQmuzMBuKdWeF4+a2sjSSpBK0iqitSQ+5BM9KhpexuGt20JpTVM7u5BDZngncgrqDMbWdxMWWOGtZ9UgbqgZE=
# bitbucket.org:22 SSH-2.0-conker_95dc3707a5 9d0e50d22058
|1|Eo6F4Y8yVeZmNYjKSr4KqCcXPpE=|pi+d+jzaqKKbzd6mSXqTzlVi1L0= ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIIazEu89wgQZ4bqs3d63QSMzYVa0MuJ2e2gKTKqu+UUO
# bitbucket.org:22 SSH-2.0-conker_95dc3707a5 f7e082ca9b56
# bitbucket.org:22 SSH-2.0-conker_95dc3707a5 1c0352a269fd
```

...or/also for double checking:

```
curl https://bitbucket.org/site/ssh

bitbucket.org ssh-rsa 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
bitbucket.org ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBPIQmuzMBuKdWeF4+a2sjSSpBK0iqitSQ+5BM9KhpexuGt20JpTVM7u5BDZngncgrqDMbWdxMWWOGtZ9UgbqgZE=
bitbucket.org ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIIazEu89wgQZ4bqs3d63QSMzYVa0MuJ2e2gKTKqu+UUO
```

Source:

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-ssh-and-two-step-verification/

#### For github.com

```
ssh-keyscan -H github.com

# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-57ca1323
|1|ZhNq+1evlmqrhCGPbv9JpU+mqJw=|MCWObOm0vqtvDg5dDUlw6uv1s9Y= ssh-rsa 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
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-57ca1323
|1|jpFa8wZoFNn8eVZWnILCyVRNlBI=|NTF31FUEZxyZO7CxoZCjkxeQ8WU= ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBEmKSENjQEezOmxkZMy7opKgwFB9nkt5YRrYMjNuG5N87uRgg6CLrbo5wAdT/y6v0mKV0U2w0WZ2YB/++Tpockg=
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-57ca1323
|1|ct+VFylgk18jtwsOsl9cH0qAtEM=|eEanGUG2m6YCdEx00XRQvJcyWfI= ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIOMqqnkVzrm0SdG6UOoqKLsabgH5C9okWi0dh2l9GKJl
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-57ca1323
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-57ca1323
```

### 2. Paste the keys into the Jenkins GUI

a) go to:
**YOUR-JENKINS-HOST-URL.com/manage/configureSecurity/**

b) scroll down to:
**Git Host Key Verification Configuration**

c) dropdown - choose:
**Manually provided host keys**

d) **paste** the keys **from the first or the second command** into the text box.

**WARNING! *Do NOT copy the keys from this answer - they are NOT to be trusted. ONLY trust host keys from the original source, such as bitbucket.org or github.com***

[image: Add host keys for bitbucket.org or github.com through Jenkins GUI]

---

PS. This was done year 2024 on Jenkins 2.426.1 in a Docker container on one server (with a separate Jenkins Agent on Ubuntu server running builds).

Answer (score 0):

issue is with the /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts. It exists in the first case, but not in the second one. This means you are running either on different system or the second case is somehow jailed in chroot or by other means separated from the rest of the filesystem (this is a good idea for running random code from jenkins).

Next steps are finding out how are the chroots for this user created and modify the known hosts inside this chroot. Or just go other ways of ignoring known hosts, such as ssh-keyscan, StrictHostKeyChecking=no or so.

Answer (score 0):

After ssh-keygen probably one only needs to copy the public key to remote host with:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/mykey user@host
```