# Unable to integrate jenkins and git

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gerrit

I am trying to integrate jenkins and git. In jenkins job configuration, I added
ssh://jenkins@x.x.x.x:29418/xxx.git. When I choose to push now or any gerrit event, build is triggered but build is failing because of the error below. I have successfully configured gerrit plugin it says success. But git client plugin is throwing following error

```
 Cloning the remote Git repository
    Cloning repository ssh://jenkins@x.x.x.x:29418/xxx.git
    git --version
    git version 1.7.9.5
    ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'xxx' : Could not clone ssh://jenkins@x.x.x.x:29418/xxx.git
    hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone ssh://jenkins@x.x.x.x:29418/xxx.git
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:226)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.AbstractGitAPIImpl.clone(AbstractGitAPIImpl.java:57)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.clone(CliGitAPIImpl.java:33)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1006)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:942)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:904)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:877)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:942)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1108)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1367)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:674)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:579)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1575)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
    Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/bin/git clone --progress -o xxx ssh://jenkins@x.x.x.x:29418/xxx.git /usr/share/tomcat7/.jenkins/jobs/xxx/workspace" returned status code 128:
    stdout: Cloning into '/usr/share/tomcat7/.jenkins/jobs/xxx/workspace'...

    stderr: Host key verification failed.
    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:790)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$100(CliGitAPIImpl.java:33)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:224)
        ... 16 more
    Trying next repository
    ERROR: Could not clone repository
    java.io.IOException: Could not clone
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1019)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:942)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:904)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:877)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:942)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1108)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1367)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:674)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:579)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1575)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jenkins Host key verification failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174194/jenkins-host-key-verification-failed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins  user (say - jksvc) is trying to connect to your git server (say git@myserver.example.com).

SSH prompts you to create ~/.ssh/known_hosts file.

In this case try to access git once on command line as 'jksvc' user and accept SSH prompts if any as "Yes"

Verify that clone is correctly create and then fire a jenkins job

Comment: .. or you can edit .ssh/known_hosts in the home directory of a jenkins service user.

Comment: At this moment jenkins is running as tomcat7, I have copied /usr/share/tomcat7/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to gerrit already. I am able to clone from the shell.

Comment: if you (as in jenkins user example jksvc) is able to clone, just check if git url is correct in jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Try using / instead of : in repo address:
ssh://jenkins@x.x.x.x:29418/xxx.git.