# Not able to connect Jenkins with Bitbucket

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh

I am using `redhat6`, `Jenkins ver. 1.609.3`,`java1.6_45` and `git 2.0.5`.
While cloning the Bitbucket repository with Jenkins I am getting bellow error.

```html
 
Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/local/git/bin/git -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:DrunkenCooder/spring3helloworld.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

[image: error screen short]

**This is the path for my git executable**

```
/usr/local/git/bin/git
```

When I go there cd / /usr/local/git/bin
and execute the command

```
 git ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:DrunkenCooder/spring3helloworld.git
```

It is getting executed successfully. and I get the bellow output

```
b148eb99dead9a288afb0c9e6f6e87ae7aa133fe    refs/heads/master
```

**Steps I followed to connect Jenkins with Bitbucket**

1. created `id_rsa` and i`d_rsa.pub` key using `ssh-keygen`

   which is there in default location. that is `home/usrname/.ssh` copy
   the content of `id_rsa.pub` key in `Bitbucket`.
2. Copied both id_rsa and id_rsa.pub file in `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh`
3. Change the permission of both file to
4. at first i had generated the key being superuser. I deleted those
   file and again generated the key using user. copied the content of
   `id_rsa.pub` in `Bitbucket`. This also dint work

tried all the solution from here [Stack-overflow solution for the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174194/jenkins-host-key-verification-failed) but dint work.
What am I missing? any idea.

Comment: As the Jenkins user, are you able to get a username from `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org`?

Answer (score 1):

Try change:

1. repository address to
   **https://bitbucket.org/DrunkenCooder/spring3helloworld.git**
2. **/usr/local/git/bin/git** to simple **git**