# Setting jenkins git returns "Host key verification failed" error

Tags: windows, git, jenkins

I want to put one of my jenkins projects into source code management with git.

However, when I typed `git@gitlab.com:myGitlabAccount/myProjectName.git` into *Repository URL* under *Source Code Management* tab in the project configuration page. I saw the following error message:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git.exe ls-remote -h git@gitlab.com:myGitlabAccount/myProjectName.git" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Host key verification failed. 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

There's no error message when I type `git.exe ls-remote -h git@gitlab.com:myGitlabAccount/myProjectName.git` under windows command line.

I can `git clone git@gitlab.com:myGitlabAccount/myProjectName.git` successfully.

And I think that [Jenkins Host key verification failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174194/jenkins-host-key-verification-failed) is a solution to my problem if I were a linux jenkins user.

But I use jenkins under windows environment, and I don't find any user called *jenkins* in windows.

How can I switch to *jenkins* user and type `git ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:person/projectmarket.git HEAD` manually in windows environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Because I installed jenkins as a windows service, I have to go to jenkins service page, and change its login account to the account I use to login windows.

In this way, jenkins can access the `known_hosts` file I used in my windows environment.

Answer (score 10):

If you installed Jenkins per default as a Windows service, you can copy a file named "known_hosts" under the directory

C:\Windows\System32\Config\SystemProfile\ .ssh

This will be read by Jenkins then and allow it to access your Git server.

Comment: This was best answer - I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You need to generate ssh keys on your jenkins machine and add them to your gitlab account

If you are using windows open git bash and type the following:

```
# generate keys
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

click <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on each step and if you already have a key you will get a warning that a certificate already exist.

Now copy the public key and paste it under you gitlab account

```
# grab the key
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Login you your gitlab account and add this key (you will see ssh-keys on the top menu once logged in)

[image]

Comment: I already generated the key-pair and pasted the public key to my gitlab account.
I can `git clone git@gitlab.com:myGitlabAccount/myProjectName.git` without any problem.

Comment: Now open gitbash and type `git fetch` you should see a question on the screen asking you to add the key to the know hosts. type yes and try to clone form jenkins

Comment: No, I don't see any response after typing `git fetch` under my local repository.

Comment: If you did not get any error its good, do the same on the jenkins machine/ account

Answer (score 1):

One alternative which worked for me is to use HTTPS rather then SSH link under "Clone or Download tab".
With SSH I am still seeing issue which i have to analyze more, but for time being HTTPS worked straight forward.