# Jenkins : Host key verification failed while executing ssh

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I am trying to create a build with basic configuration on the slave node. Only command the needs to be executed from **Execute shell**  option is doing ssh to the slave. While executing the build the following error is observed:

```
Building remotely on slave 1 in workspace /home/jenkins/workspace/slave job 1
[slave job 1] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson4772532626468045261.sh
+ ssh jenkins@172.27.170.108
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Host key verification failed.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

In order to solve the issue of **Pseduo-Termial**, added the option of **-T** while doing ssh, and still the same issue **Host Key Verification failed** :

```
Building remotely on slave 1 in workspace /home/jenkins/workspace/slave job 1
[slave job 1] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson2830119741217409056.sh
+ ssh -T jenkins@172.27.170.108
Host key verification failed.
```

After googling out got to know that ssh keys needs to be added in localhost. **Even verified that manually and no options for password were prompted while doing ssh. Below is the output:**

```
jenkins@labadmin-VirtualBox:/root/RAGHU$ ssh jenkins@172.27.170.108
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.2.0-27-generic x86_64)

* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

88 packages can be updated.
60 updates are security updates.
........
........
and reboot your system.
Last login: Fri Apr 14 14:46:50 2017 from 172.24.43.35
jenkins@RTPS-DCE-DV:~$
```

Please help in resolving these issues..

**EDIT : Adding the ssh debug info:**

```
jenkins@labadmin-VirtualBox:/root/RAGHU$ ssh -vvv jenkins@172.27.170.108
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 172.27.170.108 [172.27.170.108] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "172.27.170.108" from file "/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 63:f8:4a:65:e2:44:f2:ba:aa:25:cd:01:81:ac:f3:07
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "172.27.170.108" from file "/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '172.27.170.108' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f020b7d2f80),
debug2: key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp b3:76:7b:34:c7:dd:f8:21:07:f6:ec:19:ea:94:da:5a
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA b3:76:7b:34:c7:dd:f8:21:07:f6:ec:19:ea:94:da:5a
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 172.27.170.108 ([172.27.170.108]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env XDG_VTNR
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env VAULT_ADDR
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env SUDO_USER
debug3: Ignored env SUDO_UID
debug3: Ignored env USERNAME
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_IN
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env SUDO_COMMAND
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env LANGUAGE
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env SUDO_GID
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.2.0-27-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

88 packages can be updated.
60 updates are security updates.

......
......

and reboot your system.
Last login: Fri Apr 14 17:19:05 2017 from 172.24.43.35
jenkins@RTPS-DCE-DV:~$
```

**EDIT 2 : Adding the failed debug info :**

```
Building remotely on slave 1 in workspace /home/jenkins/workspace/slave job 1
[slave job 1] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson8556503525790261529.sh
+ ssh -vvv jenkins@172.27.170.108
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 172.27.170.108 [172.27.170.108] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 63:f8:4a:65:e2:44:f2:ba:aa:25:cd:01:81:ac:f3:07
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Host key verification failed.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins Host key verification failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174194/jenkins-host-key-verification-failed)

Comment: In order to show that I have added the ssh keys properly, I have displayed the result when tried manually for ssh to the server. I don't see any issues with ssh manually.

Comment: Are you sure you do it on the correct host and under the same user? For debugging purposes, it is helpful to add `-vvv` to see more debug information, that can come handy.

Comment: Hope the debug info will be helpful to find out the issue.

Comment: The log from the failed attempt would be more helpful.

Comment: added the log for failed attempt. and for more info adding this : jenkins@RTPS-DCE-DV:/dev$ ls -la /dev/tty
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty 5, 0 Apr 14 15:46 /dev/tty

Answer (score 0):

In your log, you can notice one interesting thing:

Your manual run:

```
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
```

Your "automatic" run:

```
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
```

Similar issue is with the `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts`. It exists in the first case, but not in the second one. This means you are running either on different system or the second case is somehow jailed in `chroot` or by other means separated from the rest of the filesystem (this is a good idea for running random code from `jenkins`).

Next steps are finding out how are the `chroot`s for this user created and modify the known hosts inside this `chroot`. Or just go other ways of *ignoring* known hosts, such as `ssh-keyscan`, `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` or so.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what should be done next to find out the issue. Please let me know that do I need to what are the commands to be executed?

Comment: Finally able to solve the issue after editing /etc/sudoers file from       
jenkins   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL to 
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Comment: That is completely unrelated to the problem you were describing (there was nowhere mentioned `sudo`)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the above comment has not resolved the issue. The main issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Ssh tries to ask you

```
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

This is because ssh fails without tty.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following lines in Jenkins init script:

```
# Disable StrictHostKeyChecking
mkdir -p ~/.ssh && touch ~/.ssh/config
echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" > ~/.ssh/config
```

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here when trying to move an existing resource from one of our servers to another. Everything was seemingly working on the old server but failed when I tried to move everything over to the new.

I was seeing something similar to the author when our CI (Bitbucket Pipelines in our case) was trying to connect - everything looked fine on the server side but it looked like the client was disconnecting:

```
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:I1Jbni6WLT89FOUyYALAC+thfmPw4m9XBiXHFnlUaCQ
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Host key verification failed.
```

This thread was very helpful - I finally realized that maybe there was something on the client side rejecting the new server... It turns out on Bitbucket you need to register pipeline SSH keys under Repository Settings / Pipelines / SSH Keys. This section allows you to setup an SSH key as you'd expect.

***BUT you also need to ensure you've updated the Known Hosts section.*** This is what I missed and once I added the fingerprint for the new host everything began working.

For what it's worth I think Joel's idea above would also work - I was going to try that next and I think it would be more universal than this Bitbucket specific approach to populate known hosts.

Answer (score 0):

It could be resolved if you add the server you're trying to connect to to the list of known hosts:

```
SERVER=jenkins@172.27.170.108              # Remote server
ssh-keyscan $SERVER >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts  # Add that server to the known_hosts list
ssh -T $SERVER                             # Connect
```

After success, the second line should be removed.

**Explanation:**

It fails for security reasons - on a connection attempt to an unknown server - it needs human supervision