# How to specify git repository in Jenkins 2.204

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm new to jenkins and installed the version 2.204 on a debian virtual machine. I also use a private git repository on this server, I do not use something like github.

I can manually checkout the repository on my windows pc via `git clone buster@192.168.136.138:/home/buster/repositories/tutorials.git` with password.

How can I specify this repository in a jenkins project? I tried this line above, but get this error message:

> Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h -- buster@192.168.136.138:/home/buster/repositories/tutorials.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
>   stdout:
>   stderr: Host key verification failed.
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins Host key verification failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174194/jenkins-host-key-verification-failed)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git error: "Host Key Verification Failed" when connecting to remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363553/git-error-host-key-verification-failed-when-connecting-to-remote-repository)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have credentials that jenkins can use to clone etc: either username/password, either a key. It should look like (example with https and username/password):

[image]