# Jenkins Host Key Verification errors in Multibranch pipeline scans

Tags: jenkins

I am seeing `Host key verification failed` errors in the Multibranch Pipeline Scan Logs of a brand new Jenkins instance, configured entirely through the [Configuration-as-Code plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin).

My Job DSL `multibranchPipelineJob` definition uses a `git@myserver.com:namespace/repo` URL in its `git` `branchSources`.

I have figured out that as soon as I change the URL from `git@` to `https://`, the error goes away, but - really - this just feels like a workaround.

As far as I understand, `multibranchPipelineJob` scans run on the Jenkins instance itself - not one of its build agents.

As such, I imagine this is simply a case of adding the host key in some `known_hosts` file, but I am not looking for the manual "log in to the server, as the `jenkins` user and add the key yourself" solution, [that has been proposed elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174194/jenkins-host-key-verification-failed).

Rather, I am wondering if anyone knows of a way to add this key either through the Configuration-as-Code `casc.yaml` file, or if this would be something I should add as a `Volume` in the `Pod` that runs Jenkins itself.