# Getting error while cofigure jenkins with git ssh key

Tags: git, github, jenkins, ssh

I am using my jenkins as a localhost i added my public key in the github and tried cloning in the machine with `git clone git@github.com:xyz/xyz.git`
it's perfectly cloning the repo commit the repo and pull push are working completely in local machine.
I wanted to use jenkins to build my jobs through jenkins with ssh i added my private key to the manage credentials in username with ssh key like this
[image]

and tried to add a new pipeline job
[image]

but i am getting the error

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h -- git@github.com:neetesshhr/sheildxwebpage.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: No ED25519 host key is known for github.com and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

i tried to follow this [link](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/setup-ssh-between-jenkins-and-github-e4d7d226b271)

But not working at all how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The actual error message is "`Host key verification failed`", which means you need to [add the remote server host key fingerprint to Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75137820/6309).

In case of GitHub, you will find said fingerprint at [`githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints`](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints), as I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708298/6309).