# Jenkins is unable to connect to a Git Repo despite having the correct credentials

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

*NOTE: in answer to the "association" of my question to the Git question cited, my problem has to do with Jenkins failing to accept a legitimate authentication. The question cited is a straight Git question having nothing to do with the Jenkins Git plugin.*

*The answer provided in the cited question, even if it is correct for Git, says nothing about how to create a key that can be used with Jenkins. Even if the problem is associated with the need for an ssl key, there is nothing in that answer that (a) tells of the need for such a key in Jenkins, or (b) tells how to create such a key in Jenkins. For this reason, the answer itself is irrelevant because it simply will not work for a Jenkins installation!*

*The bottom line: these are two very different problems whose answers aren't in the least similar. What solved a problem for the Git command line will *not* solve the problem I am having using the Git plugin for Jenkins. I am attempting to use Jenkins to set up an automated build o a Spring Boot application.*

I am attempting to use Jenkins to set up an automated build o a Spring Boot application.

My Spring Boot application is on a Git repository that is running on a Synology NAS. This NAS allows access through SSH.

When setting up my build job, I am entering the correct URL to the repository:

```
ssh://mynas/volume1/develop/myapplication
```

and I am providing the correct credentials using the Jenkins Credentials Provider:

```
Domain: Global
Kind: Username and Password
Scope: global
username: factor3
password: <my_pasword>
ID: creds
```

When I select this correct set of credentials, I keep getting the following failure from Jenkins:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h -- ssh://mynas/volume1/develop/myapplication HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Well, the repository does exist (I have been committing code to that repo for over a year now), and I made sure that the credentials I set up are the same ones I have been using to access that repository for the last year.

Have I found a bug in Jenkins' Git plugins? Or is there something I am missing here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174194/jenkins-host-key-verification-failed

Comment: `ssh-keyscan mynas >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: ??? If the problem here has to do with the need for an ssh key, then how do you get such a key into the Jenkins installation??? Your solution would work for a Git installation that sits on the same machine as the application. It will not work for Jenkins' git plugin! Furthermore, Jenkins is running in a Docker container on another machine. How do you get Jenkins to use the key???

Comment: The problem is not with user key, it's with **host key**.

Comment: PHD: I am starting to get that it is the Host key. What I am not getting is how to set up the host key. There doesn't appear to be any documentation on how to do that on a Jenkins server running in a Docker container.