# Jenkins Freestyle Project: SSH Connection Error with GitHub Repository

Tags: git, github, jenkins, ssh, devops

I am setting up a Jenkins freestyle project and encountering an issue when trying to connect to my GitHub repository using the SSH URL. The error message is as follows:

[image]

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -- git@github.com:Ihtisham-Khattak/online-resume-builder.git HEAD" returned status code 128: 
stdout: 
stderr: No ED25519 host key is known for github.com and you have requested strict checking. 
Host key verification failed. 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Here's what I have done so far:

1. Created and added both the SSH public and private keys.
2. Checked and ensured that my SSH key is added to my GitHub account.
3. Attempted to remove the old host key using ssh-keygen -R github.com.
4. Updated the SSH configuration and added GitHub-specific settings.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. I'm seeking assistance in resolving this problem so that I can successfully connect Jenkins to my GitHub repository. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I am using the Ubuntu.

I'm seeking further guidance or insights on how to resolve this issue and successfully establish the connection between Jenkins and the GitHub repository in the freestyle project.

Comment: check https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427446/stderr-no-ecdsa-host-key-is-known-for-github-com-and-you-have-requested-strict , and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174194/jenkins-host-key-verification-failed

Comment: using the ```ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts``` generate numbers of SSH babled. Now the question is where to use all of these SSH babled?