# openssh return "bad key type" with a crypto generated key pair

Tags: node.js, docker, openssh, cryptojs

I need to generate a rsa key pair on `node js` code in order to use it with an `openssh` client on an `docker` container.

I'm using the [generateKeyPair](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_generatekeypair_type_options_callback) function of `crypto` to generate keys and `parse[Private]Key` of [sshpk](https://github.com/joyent/node-sshpk#readme) to translate keys from `pem` to `openssh` format.

#### my function is :

```js
import { generateKeyPair } from 'crypto';
import sshpk from 'sshpk';

const createSShKeys = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    generateKeyPair('rsa', {
      modulusLength: 4096,
      publicKeyEncoding: {
        type: 'pkcs1',
        format: 'pem',
      },
      privateKeyEncoding: {
        type: 'pkcs1',
        format: 'pem',
      },
    }, (error, publicKey, privateKey) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        const publicKeySShEncoded = sshpk
          .parseKey(publicKey, 'pem')
          .toString('ssh');

        const privateKeySShEncoded = sshpk
          .parsePrivateKey(privateKey, 'pem')
          .toBuffer('ssh', {}) // toString('ssh') is documented, but I not find it in code.
          .toString();

        resolve({
          publicKey:  publicKeySShEncoded,
          privateKey: privateKeySShEncoded,
        });
      } 
    });
  });
};
```

I create a `docker secret` with the private key, and use it inside the container, but then I get :

```
Host key verification failed.
```

#### hint #1 : gitlab.com is not a known host

After search, I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29380672/12094975), and I have added the host fingerprint inside the `.ssh/known_hosts` file :

```
ssh-keyscan -H gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

But nothing has changed

#### hint #2 : the keys are wrong

To test the key pair, I have logged this :

```js
const {
  publicKey,
  privateKey,
} = await createSShKeys();

console.log('#PUBLIC KEY');
console.log(publicKey);

console.log('#PRIVATE KEY');
console.log(privateKey);
```

And I have stored the private key in a file. I try to verify it with :

```
$ ssh-keygen -y -t private_key
bad key type
```

#### the generated private key is as follow

https://pastebin.com/2JC7kz9r

Has anyone already generated keys with `crypto` and `sshpk` with success ?
Or encoutered similar problem ?

Thank you for your help ! :)

Comment: What problem are you actually having right now? The "Host key verification failed" error isn't related to any key that you might have generated yourself. Are you still getting that error after running ssh-keyscan?

Comment: Yup, always the same error. (I'll modify the post to indicate it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was really the key of the host, not the generated keys.

But the "clean" method doesn't work :

```sh
ssh-keyscan -H gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

The only working method is append these lines on `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```sh
Host *
   StrictHostKeyChecking no
   UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

I don't know why. (if anyone have idea ?)

But finaly, the keys are okay, it's probably a mistake on copy/paste (Lol)

Thank you all !