# docker buildkit mount ssh when using remote agent forwarding

Tags: docker, ssh, ssh-keys, docker-build, docker-buildkit

I use the `--ssh` docker buildkit feature and it works fine locally.
I want to build Docker at a remote server and for that I use the `-A` flag to forward my local github key, like:

```
ssh -i "server.pem" -A <user>@<server-ip>
```

Then in server terminal I run:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

And I get the "Hello user" message, which means the key forwarding works fine.
(In the server, `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is indeed set, and I can `git clone`)

Now, when building locally I use:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --ssh default=~/.ssh/id_rsa -t myimage:latest .
```

Which works fine.
But in the server the private key does not exists at ~/.ssh/id_rsa. So how can I forward it to docker build? 
Tried this in the server:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --ssh default=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK -t myimage:latest .
```

But it does not work.  The error is:

```
could not parse ssh: [default]: invalid empty ssh agent socket, make sure SSH_AUTH_SOCK is set
```

Even though `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is set

Docker version: 19.03

Answer (score 22):

I had a similar issue and it was fixed quite simply, I wrapped `${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}` within curly braces

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t myimage:latest --ssh default=${SSH_AUTH_SOCK} .
```

In the Docker file, I have appropriate RUN instruction to run a command that requires sensitive data

```
RUN --mount=type=ssh \
    mkdir vendor && composer install
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to have `ssh-agent` running on your machine and the key added to it with `ssh-add` or use `ssh -A -o AddKeysToAgent=true` when logging in. SSH will not automatically forward the key specified with `-i` if you set `-A` afaik. After logging in you can run `ssh-add -L` to make sure your keys were forwarded and if you see records there then `docker build --ssh default .` should work fine now.

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add server.pem
ssh -A <user>@<server-ip>
```

Comment: The key that I want to forward is not the one that I use with `-i`. I did run ssh-agent ssh-add in both client and server. And in the server when using `ssh-add -L` I do see my local key

Comment: I would also specify that the key must be named `id_rsa` or some similar default key name for this to work and under Linux, you may have AppArmor in the way. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65824786/building-go-apps-with-private-gitlab-modules-in-docker/69774987#69774987) for way more details.

Comment: Nice, i had this error cuz ssh agent was down

Answer (score 1):

Another possible cause: "Host key verification failed": in your Dockerfile, you need to either use [ssh-keyscan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214977/cloning-git-repo-causes-error-host-key-verification-failed-fatal-the-remote/29380672#29380672) to setup `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, or disable host key verification in ssh.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).