# rsync Host key verification failed

Tags: ssh, rsync

I need help on this. I'm trying to execute this line from the command line and
getting this error about host key.
my mount point is there and I verify the hosts key is there as well any help on this will much appreciated.

```sh
su oracle -c '/usr/bin/rsync -zarR --delete --exclude "lost+found" --links --rsh="ssh -i /home/oracle/.ssh/rsync_lowZone_priv" hostname:/u02 /'

Host key verification failed.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(600) [receiver=3.0.6]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

In my case I was able to just 'ssh user@host' first and it offered to auto-generate the key for me which was then saved for subsequent sessions.

Comment: Is there a way to accept the the auto generate in the one and initial command?

Answer (score 5):

I solved same problem with this command:

```sh
rsync --rsh="/usr/bin/sshpass -p "password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l root" /source/file/path username@192.168.1.1:/destination/file/path
```

Note: Be sure about each side has sshpass installation before usage.

Answer (score 4):

[Host Key Verification Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363553/git-error-host-key-verification-failed-when-connecting-to-remote-repository)

This post does good job explaining the issue. In short:

> The host key for domain.com has changed. **If this does not seem fishy to you,** you can remove the old key from your local cache using
>
> ssh-keygen -R domain.com

Answer (score 2):

first to

```
$ ssh user@server -p port
```

you need to answer to typ `yes`; then

```
sshpass -p<my_password> rsync -avzh $VOLUME_PATH/*.chk user@server:${TARGET_PATH}
```

this will be worked

Answer (score 1):

I have just hit this same issue now when trying to rsync data between 2 servers:

```
$ sshpass -p<my_password> rsync -avzh $VOLUME_PATH/*.chk user@server:${TARGET_PATH}
Host key verification failed.
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at rsync.c(638) [sender=3.1.1]
```

The error was misleading though - to fix the issue I had to **install rsync** on the *target* server as well. I am not sure why this is required but once both the *source* and *target* servers had rsync installed the copy went through.

Comment: this one works for me

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect first simply using **ssh only**, then post adding it to known hosts try sshpass, etc. as required.

> In my case, I had done a clean new install of linux distro and
> installed sshpass and it started giving errors, they all went away as
> soon as I connected first via ssh and added the remote server's IP in
> the known hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, the reason was I was using IP address which was set in Cloud Flare CDN, and CF masks IPs.
I used **domain name** instead and problem resolved.