# Host key verification failed in setup reaction commerce

Tags: node.js, git, bash, github, ssh

I would like to try and setup Reaction Commerce this [reaction-doc](https://docs.reactioncommerce.com/reaction-docs/development/installation). When I run `reaction init`, NPM error occurs in installing NPM packages.

```
5868 verbose stack Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true clone --template=C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:ongoworks/node-authorize-net.git C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-ongoworks-node-authorize-net-git-e88b3c4b
5868 verbose stack Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-ongoworks-node-authorize-net-git-e88b3c4b'...
5868 verbose stack Host key verification failed.
5868 verbose stack fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
5868 verbose stack
5868 verbose stack Please make sure you have the correct access rights
5868 verbose stack and the repository exists.
5868 verbose stack
5868 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:213:12)
5868 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
5868 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
5868 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:829:16)
5868 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
5869 verbose cwd C:\Users\...\reaction
5870 error Windows_NT 6.1.7600
5871 error argv "C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.1_1\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.1_1\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
5872 error node v4.5.0
5873 error npm  v3.10.6
5874 error code 128
5875 error Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true clone --template=C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:ongoworks/node-authorize-net.git C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-ongoworks-node-authorize-net-git-e88b3c4b
5875 error Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-ongoworks-node-authorize-net-git-e88b3c4b'...
5875 error Host key verification failed.
5875 error fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
5875 error
5875 error Please make sure you have the correct access rights
5875 error and the repository exists.
5876 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
5876 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
5877 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I found `Host key verification failed` and `Please make sure you have the correct access rights`. I already created `ssh key` in my `github` account. I can login successfully from Git Bash command(`ssh -T git@github.com`).

Do I need `special access key` for `reaction commerce`? I am confused this problem is git bash configuration problem or key verification problem in Reaction. Cos I have no experience in bit bash command.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363553/git-error-host-key-verification-failed-when-connecting-to-remote-repository

Comment: Or http://askubuntu.com/questions/45679/ssh-connection-problem-with-host-key-verification-failed-error

Comment: Under the hood, `reaction-cli` is just running this:

`git clone https://github.com/reactioncommerce/reaction.git`

What happens if you run that command directly?