# Yarn not install git private repositories

Tags: git, yarnpkg

I am using yarn but it is giving an below error for private git repositories. npm installed this repo successfully.

```
yarn install v1.2.1
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/test/testconfigs.git
Directory: /Users/admin/Projects/Demo/myProject
Output:
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Comment: it says Permission denied...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitHub Error Message - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey)

Comment: Any new solution ?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

Add the GitHub key to the list of authorized hosts:

```sh
ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Original answer:

[Git error: "Host Key Verification Failed" when connecting to remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363553/git-error-host-key-verification-failed-when-connecting-to-remote-repository)